# Javascript return false - from function

Tags: javascript, validation, forms, return-value

Is there any way to do the following:

```
validateLogin();
return false;
```

But actually like this..

```
validateLogin();
```

And here is the function:

```
function validateLogin(){
if(hi=true){
return true;
}
else{
return false
}
```

I want to attach this function for the event of a form being submitted, so if HI is false - i want to return false; meaning it will stop for form from submitting.. i know return false; will do so i just need to know how i can get this return back to the parent function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note; where it says "if (hi=true)...", this is not checking for equality, it is setting the variable. Should be "if (hi==true)...", or better yet, "if (hi)..."

Comment: Or even better, function validateLogin() { return hi; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it as follow:

```
return validateLogin();
```

however, as mmayo pointed out, don't forget about the return value:

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to stop events...

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

cresentfresh inspired me to do some research... [here is an article](http://ryancannon.com/design/css_plus_js/cancelling-events-with-javascript) with a compatibility matrix.

There are also [related threads on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help).

Comment: caveat: your example is IE only.

Comment: You know I've never bothered to check because I've only used it on our intranet.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Even though return false is supposed to work on every machine, my machine *REQUIRES* that event.returnValue be set to false. I think most machine don't need it, but it's important to know that a tiny fraction do.

Comment: In my reading this morning I saw several threads referencing the combined use of event.returnValue and preventDefault in an effort to catch most browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can eventually do that:

```
return validateLogin();
```

Note that your function code has some errors (maybe due to the simplification of the code you made to post this question?). You'd better write this method like that:

```
function validateLogin(){
  ...
  return hi;
}
```

Note also that insted of having `if (hi=true) {`, you must write `if (hi == true) {`, or better `if (hi) {`...

Answer (score 2):

```
return validateLogin();
```

This should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of stoping the default action of an event is:

```
event. preventDefault();
```

You may also want to prevent event propagation with event.stopPropgation(); to stop further event listeners from executing.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-Event

However, IE will not recognize this which is why you can set event.returnValue to false for IE.

eg:

```
if (event && event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
event.returnValue = false;
```

You can also return false from the event handler for events inlined in HTML.

```
<form onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
```

This is not considered best practice however.

Note: the event object is passed in as the first argument in your event listener.

eg:

```
function validateLogin(e) { 
   e; // is the event object
}
```

For IE you may need window.event.

```
function validateLogin(e) { 
   e = e || window.event; // is the event object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try double == (IF I==5)

Answer (score 0):

### validateLogin() Function

```
function validateLogin() {
    return hi;
}
```

### HTML block

```
<form onsubmit="return validateLogin()">
  ...
</form>
```