# prevent Scroll bubbling from element to window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, scroll

I have a modal box window (pop-up) that contains an iframe,
and inside that **iframe** there's a **div** that is scrollable.

When I scroll the iframe's inner DIV, and it has reached its top or bottom limit,
 the window of the browser itself starts to scroll. this is an *unwanted behavior*.

I've tried something like this, which kills the main window scroll when
 onMouseEnter when mouse enters pop-up box area:

`e.preventDefault()` is not working as it should for some reason...

```
$("#popup").mouseenter(function(){
   $(window).bind("scroll", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
   }); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(window).unbind("scroll");
});
```

Comment: @RoatinMarth - since nobody asked me when they had created the browser, then I am left to fix their bad UX myself. if it's not obvious why this issue is unwanted then I don't know what to tell you..

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Solved (for *some* browsers) using a simple CSS property:
 [overscroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior):

> **auto**
> The default scroll overflow behavior occurs as normal.

> **contain**
> Default scroll overflow behavior is observed inside the element this value is set on (e.g. "bounce" effects or refreshes), but no scroll chaining occurs to neighboring scrolling areas, e.g. underlying elements will not scroll.

> **none**
> No scroll chaining occurs to neighboring scrolling areas, and default scroll overflow behavior is prevented.

```css
body{
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
  overscroll-behavior: none; /*   <--- the trick    */
}

section::before{
  content: '';
  height: 200%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <input value='end' />
</section>
```

Simply apply that style property on the element which the scroll should be "locked-in" to and the scroll event will not bubble up to any parent element which might have a scroll as well.

---

#### Same demo as above but *without* the trick:

```css
body{
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}

section{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightblue;
}

section::before{
  content: '';
  height: 200%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <input value='end' />
</section>
```

Comment: `overscroll-behavior` can be a lifesaver. Unfortunately, it's not supported yet in Safari.

Comment: and on edge 18. anyone has something else to offer?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the great solution.

Comment: See more about browsers compatibility : https://caniuse.com/?search=overscroll-behavior

Comment: Works for my elements that has enough height to trigger a scrollbar being rendered. But for elements with the same class that was not that tall, they still bubbled up the scroll event! Trying to find a fix for this as well.

Answer (score 28):

Sorry, as far as I'm aware it is impossible to cancel any kind of scroll event.

Both [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20090908/#event-type-scroll) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536966%28VS.85%29.aspx) say:

```
Cancelable  No
Bubbles     No
```

I think you'll have to leave this up to browser authors to fix. Firefox (3.5 on Linux, anyway) seems to have a better behaviour for me: it only scrolls the parent if the child is already at the top/bottom end at the moment you *start* using the scrollwheel.

Comment: It can be done - and relatively easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element

Comment: Depending on your layout, you could set the container to position:fixed when the mouse enters the scrollable target and reset it back to whatever it was when the mouse leaves the scrollable target. But remember that touch devices cannot hover.

Comment: Can cancel event in chrome and FF now.

Comment: @FlavorScape how? Does event.preventDefault() work for scroll event? MSDN says otherwise...

Comment: For older IE you have to do it differently. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie otherwise, remember that you're preventing it on the window.

Comment: Sometimes I ponder whether there are any ridiculous libraries that just query selector all `*` and addEventListener('scroll'), and setInterval and make sure everything is hooked repeatedly. What were they thinking when they made scroll not bubble?! They were picturing a delusional fantasy where one person made the entire page.

Answer (score 17):

If we cannot prevent window scrolling, why not undo it?
That is, catching the scroll event and then scrolling back to a fixed position.

The following code locks the Y-Axis as long as one hovers over `$("#popup")`:

```
// here we store the window scroll position to lock; -1 means unlocked
var forceWindowScrollY = -1;

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if(forceWindowScrollY != -1 && window.scrollY != forceWindowScrollY) {
    $(window).scrollTop(forceWindowScrollY);    
  }
});

$("#popup").hover(function() {
  if(forceWindowScrollY == -1) {
    forceWindowScrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
}, function() {
  forceWindowScrollY = -1;
});
```

I use this for the query suggest box on http://bundestube.de/  (enter some characters into the top search box to make the scrollable pane visible):

[image: Screenshot]

This works flawlessly in Chrome/Safari (Webkit) and with some scrolling glitches in Firefox and Opera. For some reason, it does not work with my IE installation. I guess this has to do with jQuery's hover method, which appears to not work correctly in 100% of all cases.

Comment: I tried your site and it doesn't work for me with Chrome / Firefox / Safari on Mac

Comment: That's strange. Works perfectly here on my Mac (10.6.6). Are we talking about the same thing? I have added a screenshot for clarity. The window's scrollbars are only disabled when the mouse pointer is over the suggest box.

Comment: @zaius Could you please try again?

Comment: Ah sorry - I was trying to scroll in the box on the results page. Yes, that is working for me now. Nice work! Don't know if it's intentional, but it doesn't seem to catch the upwards scroll as well.

Comment: @zaius Great that it's working for you. Yes, the upwards scroll is intended as is. I use an additional "if(window.scrollY > forceWindowScrollY)" condition.

Comment: I've tried it on Firefox 24, Chrome 24 and IE9, and on all three it works but it's quite jerky.

Comment: I'm using chart.js with this chart zoom plugin: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.Zoom.js I wanted to zoom the chart without the page scrolling and this did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I know it's quite an old question, but since this is one of top results in google... I had to somehow cancel scroll bubbling without jQuery and this code works for me:

```
function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
    e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

document.getElementById('a').onmousewheel = function(e) { 
  document.getElementById('a').scrollTop -= e. wheelDeltaY; 
  preventDefault(e);
}
```

Comment: @vsync of course it doesn't work, as the iframe in your example is cross domain, and you cannot get events for scrolling and stuff on a cross domain iframe.

Answer (score 3):

my jQuery plugin:

```
$('.child').dontScrollParent();

$.fn.dontScrollParent = function()
{
    this.bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(e)
    {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail;

        if (delta > 0 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 0)
            return false;
        if (delta < 0 && $(this).scrollTop() >= this.scrollHeight - $(this).height())
            return false;

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: seems to, at least the `this.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(){})` part ( notice `on` instead of `bind` )

Answer (score 3):

As of now in 2018 and onwards e.preventDefault is enough.

```
$('.elementClass').on("scroll", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
 });
```

This will prevent scroll to parent.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved the problem:

I call the following when I open the popup:

```
$('body').css('overflow','hidden');
```

Then, when I close the popup I call this:

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
```

The popup is meant to be modal so no interaction is required with the underlying body

Works pretty well

Comment: It will cause the scrollbar to suddely hide and the content spread by ~16px (space which the scrollnbar previously occupied) this is not a desired UX behavior.

Comment: doesn't happen here. jsfiddle please

Comment: Obviously if you had a scroll bar and then it disappears, something has to occupy the space, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: of course. Let me double check because here it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can set [`overflow:hidden` to prevent scrolling](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/d9d43f8bef89284b). Not sure how that'd go if the doc is already scrolled. I'm also on a mouseless laptop, so no scrolly wheel testing for me tonight :-) It's probably worth a shot though.

Comment: i need it to scroll..(long text) the question doesn't revolve around that.

Comment: Yeah, my thinking is set overflow:hidden on the PARENT window. Not the iframe itself. Therefore, parent window is no longer scrollable, but the contents of the iframe are.

Comment: well, that would make the scrollbar disappear suddenly, and things will shift to the side..not such a great idea

Answer (score 0):

you can try jscroll pane inside the iframe to replace the default scroll.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

I am not sure, but give it a try

Comment: This is very interesting, thanks. I used this plugin before, its an ugly solution, but a good one for this difficult problem of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
  $('.noscroll').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(ev) {
     var prevent = function() {
         ev.stopPropagation();
         ev.preventDefault();
         ev.returnValue = false;
         return false;
     }
     return prevent();
  });
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/te8porgp/)

Use CSS `overflow:hidden` to hide the scrollbar as this will do nothing if they drag it.

Works cross-browser

Comment: makes no sense to have `prevent` function inside the cb function. if you must write you code using a `prevent` function, then take it outside so it could be used by any other even for DRY purposes, and pass it your `ev` argument. anyway, your answer has no new information or angle on the matter which was already solved.

Answer (score 0):

New web dev here. This worked like a charm for me on both IE and Chrome.

```
static preventScrollPropagation(e: HTMLElement) {
    e.onmousewheel = (ev) => {
        var preventScroll = false;
        var isScrollingDown = ev.wheelDelta < 0;
        if (isScrollingDown) {
            var isAtBottom = e.scrollTop + e.clientHeight == e.scrollHeight;
            if (isAtBottom) {
                preventScroll = true;
            }
        } else {
            var isAtTop = e.scrollTop == 0;
            if (isAtTop) {
                preventScroll = true;
            }
        }
        if (preventScroll) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't let the number of lines fool you, it is quite simple - just a bit verbose for readability (self documenting code ftw right?)

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: TypeScript. As I said, new web dev - I didn't realize that JavaScript was the defacto language when I started and TypeScript seems pretty nice so far. It actually gets compiled to JavaScript to be used by browsers.

Comment: I believe the point of a coding language is not only to communicate with machines but also to be understood by as many humans as possible, and IMHO, **javascript** is by far a better choice than **typescript**.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think javascript is more human understandable than typescript? I'm new to web dev, but I'm a pretty experienced dev in general, and I've noticed that typed languages tend to be more readable than their un-typed ancestors.

Comment: I would have to agree with Vivek, typescript is even being made the main language to use with Angular2.

Comment: @vivekmaharajh It's misleading to call un-typed languages "ancestors". Typed languages are **far** more common the more you go back in time.

Comment: @Dodekeract I should have just said "counterparts". I didn't mean to make any chronological claims :)

Comment: @vivekmaharajh You can still change it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a bit updated code that I found to work best:

```
var yourElement = $('.my-element');

yourElement.on('scroll mousewheel wheel DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
    var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail;

    if (delta > 0 && $(this).scrollTop() <= 0)
        return false;
    if (delta < 0 && $(this).scrollTop() >= this.scrollHeight - $(this).outerHeight())
        return false;

    return true;
});
```

The difference between this one and one that is already mentioned above is the addition of more events and the usage of **outerHeight()** instead of **height()** to avoid crashing if element has padding!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.scrollable').on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
    var up = false;
    if (e.originalEvent) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) up = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / -1 < 0;
        if (e.originalEvent.deltaY) up = e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0;
        if (e.originalEvent.detail) up = e.originalEvent.detail < 0;
    }

    var prevent = function () {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        e.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    if (!up && this.scrollHeight <= $(this).innerHeight() + this.scrollTop + 1) {
        return prevent();
    } else if (up && 0 >= this.scrollTop - 1) {
        return prevent();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('a');
container.onwheel = (e) => {
    const deltaY = e.wheelDeltaY || -(e.deltaY * 25); // Firefox fix
    container.scrollTop -= deltaY;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.returnValue = false;
};
```

Comment: It would be good, if you could add some explanation, to your code.

Answer (score -2):

```
function stopPropogation(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
}
```

This should work.

Comment: It didn't. and I don't understand how e.stopPropogation() will work when e.preventDefault() fails to...

Comment: You can not cancel or prevent scroll events.