# JavaScript - Cancel Scroll event

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to disable the scroll in one of my pages. I don't want to write

`scroll(0,0)` or `scrollTo(0,0)`

in the scroll event which will give a 'jumpy' nature. Can't I have something like

```
event.preventDefault()
```

for canceling the event?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window/1460020#1460020

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily although that is to temporarily disable scrolling, you can set it to permanently disable it. You should use that instead of using overflow: hidden because Chrome has a bug that you can still scroll on overflow: hidden pages using the mousewheel, arrow keys, pgup and pgdn keys, and touch scrolling if you're on a touch device. The accepted answer in that link provides a way that effectively disables it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Note that a chrome bug will still allow scrolling when overflow hidden is applied.

Comment: How to re-enable after clicking?

Answer (score 2):

The only acceptable way of preventing scrolling is making the content fit inside the window. Anything else, and you're pissing users off.

You can also use `position: fixed` CSS - but still, if it's larger than the window, the rest is unusable, so you might as well follow the suggestion #1.

Comment: There actually are many uses for cutting off content. My site uses css 3d transforms, and for some reason a useless part of it extends 10-20 pixels beyond the end of the page.

Comment: Quite the blanket statement Amadan. In my case, I want to shut down the auto scrolling (which is "pissing off" my users.) This occurs when elements from the list are added / removed. Please don't assume that a particular technique is no good, just because this particular use case could be criticized.

Comment: That's opinionated. I have a usecase where I need to temporarily keep the user from scrolling, and I can come up with plenty others.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `overflow: hidden;` will work by putting it on the `html, body` selector in CSS?

Comment: Just tested in Firefox 3.6.8 and it works by putting it on the body element.

Comment: Note that a chrome bug will still allow scrolling when overflow hidden is applied.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` that fills the whole area and set that to `overflow: hidden`. That way, you will never get scroll bars and no scroll events will be created.