# How to disable scrolling temporarily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using the scrollTo jQuery plugin and would like to know if it is somehow possible to temporarily disable scrolling on the window element through Javascript? The reason I'd like to disable scrolling is that when you scroll while scrollTo is animating, it gets really ugly ;)

Of course, I could do a `$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");` and then put it back to auto when the animation stops, but it would be better if the scrollbar was still visible but inactive.

Comment: If it is still showing, then the user is trained to think that it must be functioning. If the dose not move or dose not respond, then it will break the users mental model of how you page works and result in confusion. I would just find a better way of dealing with scrolling whilst animating, like for instance stopping the animation.

Comment: Another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280258/prevent-body-scrolling-but-allow-overlay-scrolling

Answer (score 894, accepted):

The `scroll` event cannot be canceled. But you can do it by **canceling** these interaction events:
**Mouse** *&* **Touch scroll** and **Buttons** associated with scrolling.

### [[Working demo](http://output.jsbin.com/teqoqib/6/)]

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
  if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
    preventDefault(e);
    return false;
  }
}

// modern Chrome requires { passive: false } when adding event
var supportsPassive = false;
try {
  window.addEventListener("test", null, Object.defineProperty({}, 'passive', {
    get: function () { supportsPassive = true; } 
  }));
} catch(e) {}

var wheelOpt = supportsPassive ? { passive: false } : false;
var wheelEvent = 'onwheel' in document.createElement('div') ? 'wheel' : 'mousewheel';

// call this to Disable
function disableScroll() {
  window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false); // older FF
  window.addEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); // modern desktop
  window.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt); // mobile
  window.addEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}

// call this to Enable
function enableScroll() {
  window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.removeEventListener(wheelEvent, preventDefault, wheelOpt); 
  window.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, wheelOpt);
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', preventDefaultForScrollKeys, false);
}
```

UPDATE: fixed Chrome desktop and modern mobile browsers with passive listeners

Comment: How would I disable mouse scroll?

Comment: Call `disable_scroll()` from the code above, then `enable_scroll()` after the animation ended.

Comment: Tip for other devs stuck in this trap: Do make sure you remove any and all 'e.stopPropagation()' calls from other jQuery attempts to stop scrolling, because not only does it not work, it prevents the event from bubbling to THIS code that DOES work. Hopefully my wasted 30 mins will help save someone else time :)

Comment: If using jQuery UI Dialog, I would advise renaming preventDefault() method to **anything else**, like scrollPreventDefault().  It was making my modal dialog not centered on the page.  Maybe a naming conflict in jQuery or jQuery UI?

Comment: I know the post is quite old but it was what i needed. Just one problem, its working for Safari but not for Google Chrome. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: It works in all browsers. The problem is in your code somewhere. See the working demo. http://jsbin.com/disable-scrolling/1

Comment: There is a little error that allows scrolling even when disabled. You can move the horizontal/vertical bar without problems. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I answer myself, with the second answer, the one from hallodom, it works PERFECT and it's very simple and uses less code.

Comment: Yes, it does. Do you happen to use any smooth scrolling extension?

Comment: Demo from the link is scrollable by Space/Shift+Space on Mac in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera.

Comment: You can add 32 (space) to the disabled keys array (show in the code comments).

Comment: Made an edit that now includes space blocking, just waiting for somebody to review the edit.

Comment: just returning false prevents the event...thanks to many answers like these and like 13+ more around internet i have made something
http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/CLTfS/13/embedded/result/

Comment: I can scroll this like I always do: using middle button press and moving the mouse... Therefore this trick will not affect such users as me ;)

Comment: I've refactored your helpful code into a single, self-contained object: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21533631/940252 :)

Comment: [...and here's a jQuery plugin based on your answer](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll).

Comment: I'd like to second Denis' comment about using the middle button to scroll

Comment: middle mouse button and selecting text both cause scrolling...you could disable selection but that is bad ui practice

Comment: The scrollbar is not disabled.

Comment: It works on browser emulator but not on an actual mobile device

Comment: I can still make it scroll by dragging a file over the top/bottom of the page. This also works by selecting text on the page and doing the same dragover the top/bottom.

Comment: Is there a way to use this solution for just the html/body and not overflow containers within the page?

Comment: Best solution so far for preventing scroll by showing modal. Thanks a lot

Comment: Be careful!! This method may not fit for the case where you have scroll inside your modal!

Comment: The demo doesn’t work as expected in the mobile emulator of Chrome in the developer toolbar. The scrolling continues to work despite being disabled in the demo.

Comment: "mousedown" for middle button is missing. It's used for scrolling

Comment: It is old and still works. ;) Spacebar keyCode (32) is listed in the comments. You can add it to your keys var.

Comment: In latest chrome you'll need to bind via `addEventListener` and explicitly specify the event handler as non-passive.

Comment: The demo doesn't work for me on Mac Chrome -- but does work on Mac Safari. I'm using a touchpad.

Comment: If you open side menu/bar in Youtube (any video page - not home page, bcz we already have side bar open in homepage.) it disables scrolling and hides scrollbar, i checked in Firefox and chrome, in both this same behaviour is observed. I wonder how they did it. What JS code..

Comment: on Chrome I make it work again using window.addEventListener and removing the lines with onwheel and onmousewheel

Comment: Why pass "wheel event" to the mobile listener?

Comment: Working mostly for me, but MacOS's `fn+up` and `fn+down` (which are the equivalent of home and end) still get through

Comment: Can somebody please explain the part with the `test` EventListener? I cannot understand it, it looks pretty weird...

Comment: This is a good solution and my guess is that the best existing implementation (solving edge cases like text selection, allowing selected element scroll etc.) exists in Web Components which can be used in vanilla code https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580803/1769662

Comment: I can scroll with scrollbar, it will not work for all conditions.

Comment: Using react. Had to attach it on document. Works fine. Thanks!

Comment: HTML5 breaks this answer. Adding `draggable="true"' to any element allows the page to be scrolled via edge scrolling while dragging.

Answer (score 502):

Do it simply by adding a class to the body:

```
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Add the class then remove when you want to re-enable scrolling, tested in IE, FF, Safari and Chrome.

```
$('body').addClass('stop-scrolling')
```

Comment: This worked well for me in Chrome 21.0.1180.89, IE9, FF15 & Safari 5.1.7

Comment: quick note, this appears to not work in iOS6 (presumably 5 as well). Anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Got it! You have to handle the `touchmove` event, as with `$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()})`. Edited this answer to include this mobile solution.

Comment: Cool, just have to make sure any inner scrolling can work in the modal for the touch device. Could do an overlay just underneath the modal and prevent the default touchmove on the overlay instead of body.

Comment: While this solution does work, it has the (potentially) undesirable effect of scrolling back to the top of the page.

Comment: @Matt this technique doesn't scroll to the top on our implementation on capsulecrm.com. A problem we've found recently is the modal overflows the height of the body height at 100% and controls aren't visible. We've had to have an inner scroll area on content.

Comment: Chrome bug allows scrolling when overflow is set to hidden.

Comment: Is that with height set to 100% on the body also?

Comment: This didn't work for me unless my selector was `$('body,html')`

Comment: Used @MusikAnimal solution for disabling mobile viewport scrolling while keeping it enabled on a child element with `overflow: scroll`. You can do this with `$('.child').bind("touchmove", function(e){e.stopPropagation()})`

Comment: This solution works but the scroll bar disappear and create a 'bump' effect (under window os) when you apply this class to the body (for example)

Comment: It should be noted that, as @PickYourPoison pointed out, this solution is a lot more effective using `$('body, html')` as the selector, since in many cases the height of the body does not determine the content or if the page is scrollable. Not to mention that `height: 100%` on the `body` element usually doesn't do anything if there's nothing for the `100%` to reference to.

Comment: This is great. I love how clever and simple it is. What gets me past the other issues people are having is to have `html` initially set to `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll`. (I always add `overflow-y: scroll` to `html`, can't recommend it enough). Then in `.stop-scrolling`, which is toggled only on `html`, all you need is `overflow-y: hidden`. Voila, no more content jumping around. (Works in Chrome 43.0.2357.132 (64-bit) OS X Yosemite)

Comment: This also stops the scroll event from firing. Just sayin'

Comment: @matt any workarounds for the jump-to-top issue? Been struggling with that on: http://doubledutch.me/product/spring-release-2016/

Comment: @yagudaev I did not find a solution to this issue I was happy with. Sorry :(

Comment: I tried your solution for mobile but it´s not working and css is not helping. Can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525157/prevent-background-image-from-resize-on-scrolling ?

Comment: On the jump-to-top issue, I only encountered it if the `position: fixed` property was added to the `.stop-scrolling` class. Otherwise, I don't encounter that problem as well.

Comment: Nice solution. Unfortunately it naturally prevents any pinch-to-zoom-gestures. I want to use this in the context of a fullscreen image overlay and pinch-to-zoom is quite usefull here. I think it's hard to fix this without digging quite deep right?

Comment: A fix for the jumping issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/59732981/3198804

Comment: It doesn't work if you have draggable elements

Comment: `overflow: hidden` really is the best and simplest solution for this. This prevents any weird stuttering in beetween. Simply effective. Can also just set and unset it via js instead of using classes.

Answer (score 77):

Here's a really basic way to do it:

```
window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(0, 0); };
```

It's kind of jumpy in IE6.

Comment: Not really a disabling, more like a snap to default when the scroll is attempted.

Comment: @Marcus As good as it's going to get with an event that isn't cancelable.

Comment: It may interfere with jQuery scrollTo plugin.

Comment: Even though it doesn't disable it for real, it simulates it and that's good enough for me.

Comment: I used this approach but triggering it with jquery $(document).scroll(, it was way to slow and made the page flicker in internet explorer

Comment: what i have to write when i want to enable the window scroll?

Comment: IMHO - best answer here. Plus, you don't have to lock it to `(0, 0)`, just use the current scroll position.

Comment: But how do we reenable it?

Comment: Fails with not just the jQuery scrollTo plugin, but also css `scroll-behavior: smooth` and many other things. Basically, it's not realtime, and thus is super janky

Comment: this is the best for popups

Answer (score 73):

The following solution is basic but pure JavaScript (no jQuery):

```
function disableScrolling(){
    var x=window.scrollX;
    var y=window.scrollY;
    window.onscroll=function(){window.scrollTo(x, y);};
}

function enableScrolling(){
    window.onscroll=function(){};
}
```

Comment: Jumpy in Safari 7.1 and IE 11. Newest Chrome, Firefox, Opera ok.

Comment: Still a tiny bit jumpy on newest Chrome

Comment: Working fine, In safari, chrome, but flickered in IE

Comment: If this solution not works for some browser, then that is browsers problem

Comment: As mentioned on another answer, `scroll-behavior: smooth` borks this. Also, I disagree with Oto saying that it's the browser's fault. You're basically assuming that something will happen instantly when in reality it is asynchronous

Comment: You can set `window.onscroll=null` instead of adding an empty anonymous function, `null` is the initial value of `window.onload`

Comment: This suited me the best! Thanks.

Comment: @27px Nice idea but sadly doesn't work in my tests

Comment: @LuckyLukeSkywalker Then addEventListener and removeEventListener can be used, check this tutorial: (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp)

Answer (score 28):

I'm sorry to answer an old post but I was looking for a solution and came across this question.

There are many workarounds for this issue to still display the scrollbar, like giving the container a 100% height and an `overflow-y: scroll` styling.

In my case I just created a div with a scrollbar which I display while adding `overflow: hidden` to the body:

```
function disableScroll() {
    document.getElementById('scrollbar').style.display = 'block';
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```

The element scrollbar must have this styles:

```
overflow-y: scroll; top: 0; right: 0; display: none; height: 100%; position: fixed;
```

This shows a grey scrollbar, hope it helps future visitors.

Comment: 100% neat and simple trick, minimal JS no scroll events. Just target the element we need to disable scroll and set overflow to hidden. Been writing JS and CSS for almost 10 years and I did not thought of this! Then to re-enable scroll just toggle overflow to auto!

Answer (score 25):

This solution will maintain the current scroll position whilst scrolling is disabled, unlike some which jump the user back to the top.

It's based on [galambalazs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/940252), but with support for touch devices, and refactored as a single object with jquery plugin wrapper.

**[Demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/5s01jg4s/)**

**[On github here.](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll)**

```
/**
 * $.disablescroll
 * Author: Josh Harrison - aloof.co
 *
 * Disables scroll events from mousewheels, touchmoves and keypresses.
 * Use while jQuery is animating the scroll position for a guaranteed super-smooth ride!
 */

;(function($) {

    "use strict";

    var instance, proto;

    function UserScrollDisabler($container, options) {
        // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
        // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40
        this.opts = $.extend({
            handleKeys : true,
            scrollEventKeys : [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
        }, options);

        this.$container = $container;
        this.$document = $(document);
        this.lockToScrollPos = [0, 0];

        this.disable();
    }

    proto = UserScrollDisabler.prototype;

    proto.disable = function() {
        var t = this;

        t.lockToScrollPos = [
            t.$container.scrollLeft(),
            t.$container.scrollTop()
        ];

        t.$container.on(
            "mousewheel.disablescroll DOMMouseScroll.disablescroll touchmove.disablescroll",
            t._handleWheel
        );

        t.$container.on("scroll.disablescroll", function() {
            t._handleScrollbar.call(t);
        });

        if(t.opts.handleKeys) {
            t.$document.on("keydown.disablescroll", function(event) {
                t._handleKeydown.call(t, event);
            });
        }
    };

    proto.undo = function() {
        var t = this;
        t.$container.off(".disablescroll");
        if(t.opts.handleKeys) {
            t.$document.off(".disablescroll");
        }
    };

    proto._handleWheel = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    proto._handleScrollbar = function() {
        this.$container.scrollLeft(this.lockToScrollPos[0]);
        this.$container.scrollTop(this.lockToScrollPos[1]);
    };

    proto._handleKeydown = function(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.opts.scrollEventKeys.length; i++) {
            if (event.keyCode === this.opts.scrollEventKeys[i]) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        }
    };


    // Plugin wrapper for object
    $.fn.disablescroll = function(method) {

        // If calling for the first time, instantiate the object and save
        // reference. The plugin can therefore only be instantiated once per
        // page. You can pass options object in through the method parameter.
        if( ! instance && (typeof method === "object" || ! method)) {
            instance = new UserScrollDisabler(this, method);
        }

        // Instance already created, and a method is being explicitly called,
        // e.g. .disablescroll('undo');
        else if(instance && instance[method]) {
            instance[method].call(instance);
        }

    };

    // Global access
    window.UserScrollDisabler = UserScrollDisabler;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Glad it's useful. NB I've edited with a [link to this in jQuery plugin format](https://github.com/ultrapasty/jquery-disablescroll).

Comment: Might help if the disable scroll button actually worked

Comment: @user1672694, it works here in Chrome. What's your browser and which demo page have you found the bug on? Any JS errors in the console?

Comment: On Chrome (38, Windows 7), I can still scroll by clicking and holding the middle-button down, then dragging.

Comment: On first glance [it looks like that behaviour can't be disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1930875/940252). You'd have to [disable middle-clicking](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5136883/940252) altogether, which probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: The scrollbar is not disabled.

Comment: @verism Did you click the 'toggle scrolling' button?? If you did it would be helpful to know your browser/version.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver Yes, I toggled it. I can verify the behaviour in Firefox 33.0.3. Granted the arrow keys etc don't work, but the scrollbar does. I also tested on Chrome (at work - I forget which version) with the same outcome.

Comment: @verism Thanks for highlighting. Just updated to prevent this too. Can't believe I didn't spot this before!

Comment: Also - FWIW - I tested in IE on Windows with reasonable results. IE9+ all worked, (unable to test lower versions) but with flicker: the div rapidly alternated between intended scroll position and position 0.

Comment: @verism Thanks. I've just managed to successfully test IE7-11 and I have to say I didn't see any flickering. Worth knowing that it could occur though.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver it introduces a problem on the mobile though, both mobile FF and Chrome are unable to zoom when the fingers are placed inside of the scroll-blocked div.

Comment: If the scroll-disabled element is body, spacebar and arrow keys are not functional in input elements.

Comment: Awesome plugin! Just wondering if it is at all possible to check if the scroll wheel has been triggered while scrolling is disabled? I ask because I wish to disable scroll at the start and then smooth scroll down if they use scroll wheel down. Thanks!

Comment: Please disregard, I found that binding it `mousewheel` worked a charm

Answer (score 22):

```js
var winX = null;
var winY = null;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (winX !== null && winY !== null) {
        window.scrollTo(winX, winY);
    }
});

function disableWindowScroll() {
    winX = window.scrollX;
    winY = window.scrollY;
}

function enableWindowScroll() {
    winX = null;
    winY = null;
}
```

Comment: for the type safety, I'd recommend to use negative numbers instead of null

Answer (score 8):

I was looking out for a solution to this problem but was not satisfied with the any of the above solutions (*as of writing this answer*), so I came up with this solution..

**CSS**

```
.scrollDisabled {   
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 0;// override by JS to use acc to curr $(window).scrollTop()
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
var y_offsetWhenScrollDisabled=0;

function disableScrollOnBody(){
    y_offsetWhenScrollDisabled= $(window).scrollTop();
    $('body').addClass('scrollDisabled').css('margin-top', -y_offsetWhenScrollDisabled);
}
function enableScrollOnBody(){
    $('body').removeClass('scrollDisabled').css('margin-top', 0);
    $(window).scrollTop(y_offsetWhenScrollDisabled);
}
```

Comment: I found this worked for me if I added `overflow-y: scroll` to the `.scrollDisabled` style.  Otherwise, there was a little jump as the scrollbar hid each time.  Of course, that only works for me because my page it long enough to need a scrollbar even on the largest displays.

Answer (score 8):

This answer suggests a solution for removing the "bump" that happens when `overflow: hidden` suggested in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12090055/12099556) is applied. Since an edit was declined, here it is:

---

To **remove the "bump"** that happens when `overflow: hidden` is applied, you could calculate the width of the scrollbar and substitute it with margin. Here's an example for the `body` element:

```
const bodyScrollControls = {
  scrollBarWidth: window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth,

  disable() {
    document.body.style.marginRight = `${this.scrollBarWidth}px`;
    document.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
  },
  enable() {
    document.body.style.marginRight = null;
    document.body.style.overflowY = null;
  },
};
```

If an element already has `margin-right`, getting existing one and adding scrollbar width to it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

As of Chrome 56 and other modern browsers, you have to add `passive:false` to the `addEventListener` call to make `preventDefault` work. So I use this to stop scrolling on mobile:

```
function preventDefault(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}

function disableScroll(){
    document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, { passive: false });
}
function enableScroll(){
    document.body.removeEventListener('touchmove', preventDefault, { passive: false });
}
```

Answer (score 7):

No, I wouldn't go with event handling because:

- not all events are guaranteed to reach body,
- selecting text and moving downwards actually scrolls the document,
- if at the phase of event detaching sth goes wrong you are doomed.

I've bitten by this by making a copy-paste action with a hidden textarea and guess what, the page scroll whenever I make copy because internally I have to select the textarea before I call `document.execCommand('copy')`.

Anyway that's the way I go, notice the `setTimeout()`:

```
document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:hidden;');
// do your thing...
setTimeout(function(){document.body.setAttribute('style','overflow:visible;');}, 500);
```

A momentum flashing exists as the scrollbars disappear momentarily but it's acceptable I thing.

Comment: I just had vertical scrolling on a table body (TBODY). stop: `this.table.body.style.overflowY = 'hidden'`;  restart: `this.table.body.style.overflowY = 'auto'`

Answer (score 6):

According to the **galambalazs** post I would add support for touch devices, allowing us to touch but no scroll up or down:

```
function disable_scroll() {
   ...
   document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
   }
}

function enable_scroll() {
   ...
   document.ontouchmove = function(e){ 
     return true; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is an answer not just a comment of other answer?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what you want to achieve with the removed scroll you could just fix the element that you want to remove scroll from (on click, or whatever other trigger you'd like to temporarily deactivate scroll)

I was searching around for a "temp no scroll" solution and for my needs, this solved it

make a class

```
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
```

then with Jquery

```
var someTrigger = $('#trigger'); //a trigger button
var contentContainer = $('#content'); //element I want to temporarily remove scroll from

contentContainer.addClass('notfixed'); //make sure that the element has the "notfixed" class

//Something to trigger the fixed positioning. In this case we chose a button.
someTrigger.on('click', function(){

    if(contentContainer.hasClass('notfixed')){
        contentContainer.removeClass('notfixed').addClass('fixed');

    }else if(contentContainer.hasClass('fixed')){
        contentContainer.removeClass('fixed').addClass('notfixed');
    };
});
```

I found that this was a simple enough solution that works well on all browsers, and also makes for simple use on portable devices (i.e. iPhones, tablets etc). Since the element is temporarily fixed, there is no scroll  :)

NOTE! Depending on the placement of your "contentContainer" element you might need to adjust it from the left. Which can easily be done by adding a css left value to that element when the fixed class is active

```
contentContainer.css({
    'left': $(window).width() - contentContainer.width()/2 //This would result in a value that is the windows entire width minus the element we want to "center" divided by two (since it's only pushed from one side)
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this:

This way you save 'insignificant' memory and the elements that are with `Position: fixed` didn't move and thus don't road your design itself.

**CSS** (Using CSS makes your life and memory easier)

```
html[DisableScroll] {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

html[DisableScroll] body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**JS**

```
var enableScroll = function () {
   document.documentElement
     .removeAttribute('DisableScroll');
}
```

**e.g**

```js
//When you want to enable escroll just call this function;

var enableScroll = function () {
   document.documentElement
   .removeAttribute('DisableScroll');
}
 
 setTimeout(() => {
    enableScroll();
}, 2000);
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
body{
  height: 4000px;
  background: #141417
}

html[DisableScroll] {
    overflow-y: scroll
}

html[DisableScroll] body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
}
body>p{
color: #FBFBFD
}

div{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 270px;
  background: #FBFBFD;
  color: #141417;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" DisableScroll>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body> 
    <div>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    </div>
     <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
    <p>@@@@</p><br>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This way you always have a vertical scrollbar, but as most of my content is longer than the viewport, this is ok for me. Content is centered with a separate div, but without setting margin again in body my content would stay at the left.

These are the two function I use to show my popup/modal:

```
var popup_bodyTop = 0;
var popup_bodyLeft = 0;

function popupShow(id)
{
    $('#'+ id).effect('fade');
    $('#popup-overlay').effect('fade');

    // remember current scroll-position
    // because when setting/unsetting position: fixed to body
    // the body would scroll to 0,0
    popup_bodyLeft = $(document).scrollLeft();
    popup_bodyTop  = $(document).scrollTop();

    // invert position
    var x = - popup_bodyLeft;
    var y = - popup_bodyTop;

    $('body').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('body').css('top', y.toString() +'px');
    $('body').css('left', x.toString() +'px');
}

function popupHide(id)
{
    $('#'+ id).effect('fade');
    $('#popup-overlay').effect('fade');
    $('body').css('position', '');
    $('html, body').scrollTop(popup_bodyTop);
    $('html, body').scrollLeft(popup_bodyLeft);
}
```

Result: non scrollable background and no re-positioning of the content because of the left scrollbar. Tested with current FF, Chrome and IE 10.

Comment: This worked for me and the problem of scrolling to the top after using position:fixed. Thank u!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using **[showModalDialog](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog)**, for showing secondary page as modal dialog.

to hide main window scrollbars:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

and when closing modal dialog, showing main window scrollbars:

```
document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
```

to access elements in main window from dialog:

```
parent.document.getElementById('dialog-close').click();
```

just for anybody searching about **[showModalDialog](https://github.com/niutech/showModalDialog)**:(after line 29 of original code)

```
document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";//****
document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";//****
    dialog.close();
});
```

Comment: This worked for me in React where jQuery is non existent and where React does not have access to manage the state of the body tag.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest solution I got so far. And believe me I tried all the others and this is the easiest one. It works great **on Windows devices**, which pushes the page from the right to have room for the system scrollbar and **IOS devices** which don't require space for their scrollbars in the browsers. So by using this you wont need to add padding on the right so the page doesn't flicker when you **hide the overflow of the body or html with css**.

The solution is pretty simple if you think about it. The idea is to give the **window.scrollTop()** the same exact position at the moment that a popup is opened. Also change that position when the window resizes ( as the scroll position changes once that happens ).

So here we go...

First lets create the variable that will let you know that the popup is open and call it **stopWindowScroll**. If we don't do this then you'll get an error of an undefined variable on your page and set it to 0 - as not active.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    stopWindowScroll = 0;
});
```

Now lets make the open popup function witch can be any function in your code that triggers whatever popup you are using as a plugin or custom. In this case it will be a simple custom popup with a simple document on click function.

```
$(document).on('click','.open-popup', function(){
    // Saving the scroll position once opening the popup.
    stopWindowScrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Setting the stopWindowScroll to 1 to know the popup is open.
    stopWindowScroll = 1;
    // Displaying your popup.
    $('.your-popup').fadeIn(300);
});
```

So the next thing we do is create the close popup function, which I repeat again can be any function you already have created or are using in a plugin. The important thing is that we need those 2 functions to set the **stopWindowScroll** variable to 1 or 0 to know when it's open or closed.

```
$(document).on('click','.open-popup', function(){
    // Setting the stopWindowScroll to 0 to know the popup is closed.
    stopWindowScroll = 0;
    // Hiding your popup
    $('.your-popup').fadeOut(300);
});
```

Then lets create the window.scroll function so we can prevent the scrolling once the **stopWindowScroll** mentioned above is set to 1 - as active.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(stopWindowScroll == 1) {
         // Giving the window scrollTop() function the position on which
         // the popup was opened, this way it will stay in its place.
         $(window).scrollTop(stopWindowScrollPosition);
    }
});
```

Thats it. No CSS required for this to work except your own styles for the page. This worked like a charm for me and I hope it helps you and others.

Here is a working example on JSFiddle:

**[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/BinaryForest/rhucyp50/)**

Let me know if this helped. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

I found that changing the style of body was not necessary.

The only thing we need is to prevent the whole document (html element) from having a y scrolling.

We can create and destroy a style sheet with Javascript to do that. Here's how I do it:

https://jsfiddle.net/3os72ryk/

```
let scroll_style_element;

function disable_scrolling(){
    
  // Create a style sheet we will only use to disable scrolling :
  scroll_style_element = document.createElement('style');
  document.head.appendChild(scroll_style_element);
  const scroll_style_sheet = scroll_style_element.sheet;
    
  scroll_style_sheet.insertRule('html{height:100%;overflow-y:hidden;}', scroll_style_sheet.cssRules.length);
}

function enable_scrolling(){
  if( scroll_style_element ) document.head.removeChild(scroll_style_element);
}
```

Very interested to know if anyone finds something wrong with this approach, so please comment below if you do.

Comment: Implemented on react application successfully! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this? (If you're using jQuery)

```
var $window = $(window);
var $body = $(window.document.body);

window.onscroll = function() {
    var overlay = $body.children(".ui-widget-overlay").first();

    // Check if the overlay is visible and restore the previous scroll state
    if (overlay.is(":visible")) {
        var scrollPos = $body.data("scroll-pos") || { x: 0, y: 0 };
        window.scrollTo(scrollPos.x, scrollPos.y);
    }
    else {
        // Just store the scroll state
        $body.data("scroll-pos", { x: $window.scrollLeft(), y: $window.scrollTop() });
    }
};
```

Comment: a bit jumpy, but this works for IE 7 (client uses it). other solutions do not.

Answer (score 3):

Cancelling the event's as in the accepted answer is a horrible method in my opinion :/

Instead I used `position: fixed; top: -scrollTop();` below.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/w9w9hthy/5/

From my jQuery popup project: https://github.com/seahorsepip/jPopup

```
//Freeze page content scrolling
function freeze() {
    if($("html").css("position") != "fixed") {
        var top = $("html").scrollTop() ? $("html").scrollTop() : $("body").scrollTop();
        if(window.innerWidth > $("html").width()) {
            $("html").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
        }
        $("html").css({"width": "100%", "height": "100%", "position": "fixed", "top": -top});
    }
}

//Unfreeze page content scrolling
function unfreeze() {
    if($("html").css("position") == "fixed") {
        $("html").css("position", "static");
        $("html, body").scrollTop(-parseInt($("html").css("top")));
        $("html").css({"position": "", "width": "", "height": "", "top": "", "overflow-y": ""});
    }
}
```

This code takes, width, height, scrollbar and pagejump issues into consideration.

Possible issues resolved with above code:

- width, when setting position fixed the html element width can be smaller then 100%
- height, same as above
- scrollbar, when setting position fixed the page content no longer has a scrollbar even when it had a scrollbar before resulting in a horizontal pagejump
- pagejump, when setting position fixed the page scrollTop is no longer effective resulting in a vertical pagejump

If anyone has any improvements to above page freeze/unfreeze code let me know so I can add those improvements to my project.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest method is:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); // Remove the scroll bar temporarily
```

To undo it:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

Easy to implement, but the only downside is:

- The page will jump a bit to the left if it is center-aligned (horizontally).

This is due to the scroll bar being removed, and the viewport becoming a bit wider.

Comment: that will reset the scroll position

Comment: @AngelDavidCalderaroPacciott No, the scroll position will remain the same height/distance.

Comment: @Daan it does reset the scroll position on Chrome

Comment: @Tom I just checked it, it only does it on some occassions (when the body height isn't relative to its children). Please try changing `body` to `html` instead.

Comment: I bet you didn't check your solution in Iphone cause `overflow:hidden` doesn't work in there

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to stop the scroll (no jQuery). I use it to disable the scroll when the side menu appears.

```html
<button onClick="noscroll()" style="position:fixed; padding: 8px 16px;">Disable/Enable scroll</button>
<script>
var noscroll_var;
function noscroll(){
  if(noscroll_var){
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflowY = "";
    document.body.style.paddingRight = "0";
    noscroll_var = false
  }else{
    document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute('style', 'overflow-y: hidden !important');
    document.body.style.paddingRight = "17px";
    noscroll_var = true
  }
}/*noscroll()*/
</script>

<!-- Just to fill the page -->
<script>
  for(var i=0; i <= 80; i++){
    document.write(i + "<hr>")
  }
</script>
```

I put 17px of padding-right to compensate for the disappearance of the scroll bar. But this is also problematic, mostly for mobile browsers. Solved by getting the bar width according to [this](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=115).

[All together in this Pen.](https://codepen.io/josep81/pen/jLgdwz)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the jump, this is what I used

```
export function toggleBodyScroll(disable) {
  if (!window.tempScrollTop) {
    window.tempScrollTop = window.pageYOffset; 
    // save the current position in a global variable so I can access again later

  }
  if (disable) {
    document.body.classList.add('disable-scroll');
    document.body.style.top = `-${window.tempScrollTop}px`;
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('disable-scroll');
    document.body.style.top = `0px`;
    window.scrollTo({top: window.tempScrollTop});
    window.tempScrollTop = 0;
  }
}
```

and in my css

```
.disable-scroll {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had to do something very similar, and after some time looking for an answer and trying different approaches, I ended up using a very easy solution.

My problem was very similar, almost identical, the only difference is I didn't have to actually show the scroll bar - I just had to make sure its width would still be used, so the page's width would not change while my overlay was displayed.

When I start sliding my overlay into the screen, I do:

```
$('body').addClass('stop-scrolling').css('margin-right', 8);
```

and after I slide my overlay off the screen I do:

```
$('body').removeClass('stop-scrolling').css('margin-right', 0);
```

**IMPORTANT:** this works perfectly because my overlay is positioned `absolute`, `right: 0px` when `visible`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Cheyenne Forbes' answer, and one I found here via fcalderan: [Just disable scroll not hide it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it)
and to fix Hallodom's issue of the scrollbar disappearing

CSS:

```
.preventscroll{
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

JS:

```
whatever.onclick = function(){
    $('body').addClass('preventscroll');
}
whatevertoclose.onclick = function(){
    $('body').removeClass('preventscroll');
}
```

This code does jump you to the top of the page, but I think that fcalderan's code has a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, below is the way I handle it.

```
/* file.js */
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
//if window dont scroll
body.classList.add("no-scroll");
//if window scroll
body.classList.remove("no-scroll");

/* file.css */
.no-scroll{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar issue on touch devices. Adding "touch-action: none" to the element resolved the issue.

For more information. Check this out:-

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action

Answer (score 2):

This code will work on **Chrome 56** and further (original answer doesn't work on Chrome anymore).

Use `DomUtils.enableScroll()` to enable scrolling.

Use `DomUtils.disableScroll()` to disable scrolling.

```
class DomUtils {
  // left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
  // spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
  static keys = { 37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1 };

  static preventDefault(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
  }

  static preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (DomUtils.keys[e.keyCode]) {
      DomUtils.preventDefault(e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  static disableScroll() {
    document.addEventListener('wheel', DomUtils.preventDefault, {
      passive: false,
    }); // Disable scrolling in Chrome
    document.addEventListener('keydown', DomUtils.preventDefaultForScrollKeys, {
      passive: false,
    });
  }

  static enableScroll() {
    document.removeEventListener('wheel', DomUtils.preventDefault, {
      passive: false,
    }); // Enable scrolling in Chrome
    document.removeEventListener(
      'keydown',
      DomUtils.preventDefaultForScrollKeys,
      {
        passive: false,
      }
    ); // Enable scrolling in Chrome
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i use this simple trick here:

```
.no-scroll{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
let toggle_scrolling_state = () => {
   element.classList.toggle("no-scroll");
}
```

and then call the function when you want to stop scrolling on a event or ...

Answer (score 2):

Toggle the  overflowY with a Javascript function at the same time you toggle your mobile menu's visibility. Like this for example:

```
function handleClickMobileMenu() {
  document.body.style.overflowY = isMobileMenuOpen ? "hidden" : "scroll";
  //...
}
```

Call the function when you toggle the mobile menu on and off.
Best use case is when your mobile menu is taking full viewport area.

Answer (score 1):

> Store scroll length in a global variable and restore it when needed!

```
var sctollTop_length = 0;

function scroll_pause(){
  sctollTop_length = $(window).scrollTop();
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
}

function scroll_resume(){
  $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
  $(window).scrollTop(sctollTop_length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on another [site](http://phonegapcmsworld.blogspot.com/2013/02/disable-page-scroll-on-jquerymobile.html):

Disable scroll:

```
$( ".popup").live({
    popupbeforeposition: function(event, ui) {
    $("body").on("touchmove", false);
}
});
```

After close popup release scroll:

```
$( ".popup" ).live({
    popupafterclose: function(event, ui) {
    $("body").unbind("touchmove");
}
});
```

Comment: That only seems to stop touch scrolling, but the mouse scrolling, arrow keys, page up and down keys, etc will still work. -1

Comment: These 'events' are for touch scrolling, just substitute whatever events you need.

Comment: also, this seems to be used in some other very specific situation. popupbeforeposition? What is that supposed to be for? What does this have to do with temporarily disabling scrolling? At least make it relevant to this situation. It looks like you copied this directly from a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can block the spacebar scroll and hide the browser scrollbar:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
        return false;

    }
});

document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
document.body.scroll = 'no';
```

Comment: Disabling space bar key is really a no-go solution

Answer (score 0):

galambalazs's solution is great! It worked perfectly for me in both Chrome and Firefox. And it also may be extended to prevent any default event from the browser window.
Let's say you are doing an app on the canvas. You could do this:

```
var events = {
  preventDefault: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;  
  },

  //spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36,
  //left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40
  keys: [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
  keydown: function(e) {
    for (var i = events.keys.length; i--;) {
      if (e.keyCode === events.keys[i]) {
        events.preventDefault(e);
        return;
      }
    }
  },

  wheel: function(e) {
    events.preventDefault(e);
  },

  disable: function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', events.wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = events.wheel;
    document.onkeydown = helpers.events.keydown;
  },

  enable: function() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
      window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', events.wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
  }
}
```

And then on your app let's say you're going to process your own events, like mouse, keyboard, touch events and so on... You could disable default events when the mouse goes inside the canvas and re-enable them when the mouse goes out:

```
function setMouseEvents(canvas) {
  var useCapture = false;

  //Mouse enter event
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
    events.disable();
  }, useCapture);

  //Mouse leave event
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event) {
    events.enable();
  }, useCapture);
}
```

You could even disable right click menu with this hack:

```
function disableRightClickMenu(canvas) {
  var my_gradient = canvas.context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 225);
  my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
  my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
  canvas.context.fillStyle = my_gradient;
  canvas.context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the following CSS with JavaScript will help. I'm not as good as the others here but this worked for me.

```
body {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: So an answer based on mine got upvotes but mine got only downvotes? Why does stackoverflow hate me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar animation problem on mobile screens but not on laptops, when trying to animate a div using jquery's animate command. So I decided to use a timer that restored the window's scroll position so frequently  that to a naked eye the document would appear static. This solution  worked perfectly on a small screen mobile device like Samsung Galaxy-2 or iphone-5.

**Main Logic of this approach**: The timer to set window's scroll position to original scroll position should be started before the jquery animate command, and then when animation is completed we need to clear this timer (`original scroll position` is the position just before animation starts).

*I found to my pleasant surprise* that the document actually appeared static during the animation duration if the timer interval was `1 millisecond`, which is what I was aiming for.

```
//get window scroll position prior to animation
//so we can keep this position during animation
var xPosition = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft;
var yPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;

//NOTE:restoreTimer needs to be global variable
//start the restore timer
restoreTimer = setInterval(function() {
    window.scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition);
}, 1);

//animate the element emt
emt.animate({
    left: "toggle",
    top: "toggle",
    width: "toggle",
    height: "toggle"
}, 500, function() {
    //when animation completes, we stop the timer
    clearInterval(restoreTimer);
});
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION that worked**: Based on the answer by Mohammad Anini under this post to enable/disable scrolling, I also found that a modified version of code as below worked.

```
//get current scroll position
var xPosition = window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft;
var yPosition = window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;

//disable scrolling
window.onscroll = function() {
    window.scrollTo(xPosition, yPosition);
};

//animate and enable scrolling when animation is completed
emt.animate({
    left: "toggle",
    top: "toggle",
    width: "toggle",
    height: "toggle"
}, 500, function() {
    //enable scrolling when animation is done
    window.onscroll = function() {};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this issue also includes a concern with the body width, as the page seems to dance a little when we hide the scroll bar with `overflow = "hidden"`.
The following code works perfectly for me, and is based on an Angular approach.

```
element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
    var w = document.body.offsetWidth;
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.body.style.width = w + 'px';
});

element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'initial';
    document.body.style.width = 'auto';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that worked for me (disabling window scrolling temporarily).

Based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dh834zgw/1/

the following snippet (using jquery) will disable the window scroll:

```
 var curScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
 $('html').toggleClass('noscroll').css('top', '-' + curScrollTop + 'px');
```

And in your css:

```
html.noscroll{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    z-index: 10;
 }
```

Now when you remove the modal, don't forget to remove the noscroll class on the html tag:

```
$('html').toggleClass('noscroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I've just put together:

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/tamevht0/)

```js
document.onwheel = function(e) {
  // get the target element
  target = e.target;
  // the target element might be the children of the scrollable element
  // e.g., "li"s inside an "ul", "p"s inside a "div" etc.
  // we need to get the parent element and check if it is scrollable
  // if the parent isn't scrollable, we move up to the next parent
  while (target.scrollHeight <= target.clientHeight) {
    // while looping parents, we'll eventually reach document.body
    // since body doesn't have a parent, we need to exit the while loop
    if (target == document.body) {
      break;
    }
    target = target.parentElement;
  }
  // we want this behaviour on elements other than the body
  if (target != document.body) {
    // if the scrollbar is at the top and yet if it still tries to scroll up
    // we prevent the scrolling
    if (target.scrollTop <= 0 && e.deltaY < 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    // similarly, if the scrollbar is at the bottom and it still tries to scroll down
    // we prevent it
    else if (target.clientHeight + target.scrollTop >= target.scrollHeight && e.deltaY > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  background: gainsboro;
}

#box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: white;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
  overflow-y: hidden
}

Javascript
``let body = document.querySelector('body');
if(condition)  {
 //disable scroll on the entire body
 body?.classList.add("disable-scroll");
} 
else {
 //to remove the class attrib
 body?.removeAttribute("class");
 //or to remove the disable-scroll class only
 body?.classList.remove("dissble-scroll");
}
```

This is way better than long code. easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in this post. In my context I wish deactivate vertical scroll when I'm scrolling horizontally inside a

Like this =>

```js
let scrollContainer = document.getElementById('scroll-container');
document.getElementById('scroll-container').addEventListener(
    "wheel",
    (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollContainer.scrollLeft += event.deltaY;
    },
    {
        // allow preventDefault()
        passive: false
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Site I have inherited, had a scroll on links. To disable this scroll on click on specific button temporary, this worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('button.class-name').click(function(event) {
        disableScroll();
        setTimeout(enableScroll, 500);  
    });
});


function disableScroll() {
    scrollTop =  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
    scrollLeft =  window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft, 

    window.onscroll = function() { 
            window.scrollTo(scrollLeft, scrollTop); 
    };
}

function enableScroll() { 
    window.onscroll = function() {}; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this gives no content jump whatsoever.

To disabled scrolling:

```
this.htmlBody = $('body')
this.scrollPos = document.documentElement.scrollTop
this.htmlBody.css('top', -this.scrollPos + 'px').addClass('disable-scroll')
```

To re-enable scrolling:

```
this.htmlBody.removeClass('disable-scroll')
$(window).scrollTop(this.scrollPos)
```

And the CSS:

```
body.disable-scroll {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
you can use this code line inside your function and works on the specific element it's being clicked.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.

Comment: it's not the same approach

Answer (score 0):

Setting `pointer-events: none` can also be a solution if the content inside doesn't has to clickable. Disables scrolling, wheeling and arrow keys.

Answer (score -1):

There is **another solution**!

Instead of use multiple event listeners and add, stop and off them hardly, you can **add listener just once** with callback, in which you can **share event throughout your functions**, call preventDefault only where and when it needed and so on, even implement own event priority system.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer. It is unclear which listener you are referring to, how sharing the event throughout functions is necessary, and where preventDefault is supposed to be applied.

Answer (score -5):

I found a better, but buggy way, combining sdleihssirhc's idea:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY);
    //Or
    //window.scroll(window.scrollX, window.scrollY);
    //Or Fallback
    //window.scrollX=window.scrollX;
    //window.scrollY=window.scrollY;
};
```

I didn't test it, but I'll edit later and let you all know. I'm 85% sure it works on major browsers.

Comment: You need to store the old values of window.scrollX and window.scrollY outside the function to freeze the scrolling, otherwise it is useless!