# Scroll dialog body but not the page below it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dialog(with scrollable content body) on top of a page that's also scrollable. Now I want that when I try to scroll, from inside the dialog using mouse wheel, only the dialog body should scroll and not the page below it.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Do you mean that the dialogue window should scroll even if it's out of focus and the main window is in focus?

Comment: nope! I want 'scroll the one which is in focus'!

Comment: Then it's the default behaviour. Just assign the dialogue box `overflow-y` CSS property to `auto`.

Comment: tried this out, but just after the dialog height has been scrolled, it starts scrolling the page body.. I want to prevent this until the page body itself gets focus and is scrolled

Answer (score 2):

You could try wrapping all your content into a block with `overflow: auto` and set the `overflow` property of the window to `hidden`.

See example [here](http://jsbin.com/ofazuf).

I don't think you can prevent the window from scrolling otherwise. See similar question: [prevent Scroll "bubbling" from element to window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window#answer-1460020).

Another answer suggests you can prevent the mouse-wheel event's default effect: [Prevent scrolling of parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element#answer-5802887).  But it's not ideal as scrolling also occurs upon pressing keys, selecting text and so on.