# Preventing scroll of parent element

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prevent scrolling of parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element)

Say I have two elements as such:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child">
Hello
</div>
</div>
```

Both elements have overflow-y: scroll.  When I scroll inside the `#child`, when I reach the bottom of the scroll, **the `#parent` scroll initiates**.  That's what I'm trying to prevent.  I don't want to `#parent` element to scroll when my mouse is in the `#child` element.

Comment: Prevent the scroll event from bubbling to its parent

Comment: I don't think so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window