# Is there a better way to lock the main scroll bar without hiding it in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, gwt

I set my body element to

```
body {
   overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

This creates a scroll bar on my body element. When I create a scrollbar and scroll to the bottom the main area of my page is also scrolled.

I found some posts on this topic: [Prevent scrolling of parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element) [prevent Scroll "bubbling" from element to window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459676/prevent-scroll-bubbling-from-element-to-window) but these are not applicable for GWT.

I tried the following:

```
@UiHandler("panel")
void onPanelMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
    Window.enableScrolling(false);
}


@UiHandler("panel")
void onPanelMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
    Window.enableScrolling(true);
}
```

This is a bad solution because the main scroll bar disappear and the page is moving from left to right and back. I want to lock the scroll bar not hide it. Hiding will move the screen.

**Is there a better way to lock the main scroll bar in GWT?**

Comment: check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/just-disable-scroll-not-hide-it?rq=1 , according to this answer you may  need to  use some JSNI (Gquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose only gwt introduced concept of layout panels. Use `RootLayout Panel` and other layout panels. Then your applications won't have body scrolls if you maintain the hierarchy. Layout panels also resizes child widgets on browser resize.  So you will get an added advantage

**EDIT**

If you want a fixed header and scroll on the rest of the part, use RootLayoutPanel and add DockLayoutPanel to it. Set your header panel to dockPanel North side and add scroll panel to the center of the dockPanel

```
FlowPanel headerPanel = new FlowPanel();
headerPanel.setWidth("100%");

ScrollPanel bodyPanel = new ScrollPanel();

DockLayoutPanel myApp = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.PX);
myApp.addNorth(headerPanel, 100);
myApp.add(bodyPanel);

RootLayoutPanel.get().add();
```

Comment: The problem with layout panels is that you do not get a scroll bar on the body. This is needed to make a fixed header. If you add a ScrollPanel to the RootLayoutPanel add a fixed header with width 100% then the header overlaps the ScrollPanel.

Comment: But how does this solve my problem? Is the scroll event not bubbling to the parent scroll panel?

Comment: When I use DockLayoutPanel will it work when I do event.preventDefaults() and event.stopPropagation() ?

Answer (score -1):

To hide and lock the scrollbar of the body

```
  body {
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Window.enableScrolling(false); does that. This is exactly what I don't want.

Comment: I want to lock the scroll bar not hide it. Hiding will move the screen.

Comment: Well you question should be then :Is there a better way to lock the main scroll bar without hidding it in GWT?

Comment: Okay, can you answer this question?