# Scroll on long content in iframe briefly interrupts when bottom of parent container is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, scroll

I have a web page with a JQuery tab containing an iframe.

When I scroll within that iframe (on long content, that continues off the visible page), the iframe scrolling briefly pauses 2-3 seconds near the bottom of the iframe, before completing the scroll (after activating the scrolling of the parent container).

By illustration, that behavior is similar to that shown in the "*Same demo as above but without the trick*" in this StackOverflow post,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202811/1904943

where when you scroll the section with the light blue background, the scrolling of that section pauses, then completes as the outer section activates.

How can I override this behavior, i.e. seamlessly complete the scrolling of the iframe content, regardless of the status of the parent container?

Comment: ***Workaround:*** Since I am displaying HTML files within the iframe, I found that padding the bottom of those files with a bit of blank space alleviates the problem described in my question. That is, I am able to scroll to the bottom of the iframe (HTML) content and into that padding, before triggering the scrolling of the parent `<div>`. CSS file addition: `html {padding-bottom: 10rem;}`