# Incompatibility between Struts 2 and Chrome extension

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, struts2

I wrote a Google-Chrome extension, running fine on all (tested) sites, except on a web site built with Struts 2 framework.

In 'content.js' script of my extension, I capture two events like this:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', clickDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', clickUpHandler, false);
```

None of those events handlers are ever called.

Is Struts2 incompatible with Google-Chrome extensions?

Any idea?

Comment: check if that website has some old struts-dojo stuff that may need to be upgraded

Comment: What is the problem .. ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found my problem. The host page is containing html frames.

By default, my Chrome plugin was not designed to handle events of those frames. 
A little modification in the manifest.json file of the Chrome plugin resolved this issue. 
The relevant parameter was: "all_frames".

See: [developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks are completely irrelevant to chrome extensions.
In the end the client side of all frameworks end up using the DOM.
You must have some other problem going.

Comment: I do not agree with you. The Struts2 framework not only produce a DOM, it creates also a lot of Javascript in the browser.
Let us putting the Chrome extension problem aside.
Can you explain me why the following Javascript line doesn't work when typed in the console of the Struts2 web site:
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){alert("duh")}, false);
In other sites, the duh alert box is showing when clicking on the page.
There seem to be something configured by the Strut2 application that  doesn't allow to use document.addEventListener.

Comment: What I meant to say is that its not a Chrome extensions issue, its a "regular" javascript issue that could happen with any page. For example another addEventListener handler that was added before yours could be preventing default and propagation to other handlers. See here for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731459/how-to-use-javascripts-addeventlistener-to-override-an-html-forms-default-su

Comment: I finally found my problem. The host page is containing html frames. By default, my Chrome plugin was not designed to handle events of those frames. A little modification in the manifest.json file of the Chrome plugin resolved this issue. The relevant parameter was: "all_frames". See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts for explaination.
Again, thx for your support