# How to stop a page from jumping to the top after clicking link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a filter and when you try to change the level of experience the page goes to the very top. my code looks like this:

Visual: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ3Y6.jpg

```
<ul class="SecondNavigation">
<li>
    <nav class="CategoriesNaviation">
        <h3>Experience Filter</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                    <span>No Filter</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li class="Selected">
                <a href="/Beginner/">
                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                    <span>Beginner</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Intermediate/">
                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                    <span>Intermediate</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/Advance/">
                    <i class="fa fa-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i>
                    <span>Advance</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</li>
```

Question: Is there a way to disable the page from moving to the top after the user clicks on the anchor?

Comment: Step 1.
intercept the click with javascript

Step 2.
Store current scroll position in a cookie/localstorage

Step3
create a onload page event in javascript

step4
fetch the scoll value from cookie/localstore and set it with javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault), or
- `return false`

Both will have the effect of prevent the default behavior of internal anchor links from navigating to the top of the page. Example usage, as has been [demonstrated on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731459/how-to-use-javascripts-addeventlistener-to-override-an-html-forms-default-su):

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a"),
    pd = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

    };

links.addEventListener('click', pd, false);
```

If you're using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var links = $('a');
links.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Can be used anywhere
});
```

Important to note that if you choose to use `return false`, it has to be on the last line in the function, otherwise it will stop all downstream code from being executed:

```
var links = $('a');
links.click(function() {
    // Your code here
    // ...

    return false; // Must be on the last line
});
```

Perhaps some bedtime reading?

- [The difference between ‘return false;’ and ‘e.preventDefault();’](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)
- [When and why to 'return false' in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855360/when-and-why-to-return-false-in-javascript)