# handling ctrl + key event in IE browser

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, internet-explorer, key-events

I'm using hotkeys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>) in my flex application. getting problem when my app is running in IE.
when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, im getting 'Add a Favorite' window of IE.

How should I override the default behaviour of the browser? if possible, give me some example.

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler, try

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

See this SO thread: [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help)