# ctrl + number key using javascript in browser to trigger an event

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [handling ctrl + key event in IE browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364004/handling-ctrl-key-event-in-ie-browser)

I want to use `ctrl + key` (any number) so that it triggers a javascript event, but if I do that then, the browser changes tab (like it is supposed to do usually).

Is there a way of doing what I would like to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jquery.hotkeys**

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

Very easy to work with keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

In your `keydown` event handler, use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode < 58 && e.ctrlKey == true) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
}
```

This doesn't work in IE8 and below, however, and I can't seem to find a solution that works with `attachEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

**Shortcut Library (5.66 Kb Standalone)**

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+1",function() {
    alert("Hello World!");
});
```