# Explorer following my link in jquery example

Tags: jquery

Using http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js plugin.

```
$(document).on('click','button.submitButton', function(e){

      var options = { 
        target:'#comment_results',  
        success: function() { 
                $('#comment_results').fadeIn('slow');
                $('#status_notification').fadeOut('slow');          
            } 
    }; 

    // pass options to ajaxForm 
    $(this).closest('form').ajaxForm(options);
    $(this).closest('form').ajaxSubmit();

     e.preventDefault(); // stop the browser from following the link 
    });
```

Internet explorer version 10 not stopping the browser from following my link. Works fine in firefox and chrome. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's better ask it from them http://www.malsup.com

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479216/does-internet-explorer-supports-e-preventdefault

Comment: Have you tried moving `e.preventDefault()` to the beginning of the function?