# How to cancel submit in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I've been struggling to make this work for quite some time. I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
    ...
    });
});
```

I've found in most of the places, including on the jQuery site, that this will prevent the form from being submitted:

```
return false;
```

It doesn't.

Next I've read all related question and answers on this site and tried them all out.
In Chrome and Firefox this works:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

In IE8 it doesn't. I've read that IE doesn't support this and we should use this:

```
event.returnValue = false;
```

Although several people confirm that it worked for them (e.g. [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE. Any help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help)), it doesn't for me. I'm not sure why though. I have a form with a submit button, nothing special, but, even if I put only this piece of code, the form is still submitted:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

One last thing: I've read that we should test this first before calling preventDefault():

```
if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); }
```

But in IE8, event.preventDefault exists and no error is thrown. How can that be if it's unsupported by IE?

**Update 1:** I've tried a simplified version with the following code:

CancelSubmitTest.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CancelSubmitTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="HtmlEditor.CancelSubmitTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/CancelSubmit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server"
            Text="Save" OnClick="SaveButtonClick" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="SomeValidationGroup" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CancelSubmitTest.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace HtmlEditor
{
    public partial class CancelSubmitTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void SaveButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

CancelSubmit.js

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
    });
});
```

It's a pretty straight-forward example. The JavaScript code is executed but the form is still submitted, although I set event.returnValue to false. What am I doing wrong?

**Update 2:** I've changed the javascript code in the simplified project as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        return false;
    });
});
```

It works in IE but I still have to figure out why it doesn't work in my application. Thanks to everyone for your help.

Comment: Read about [jQuery's event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Yes `preventDefault` is normally unsupported by IE, but jQuery is cross-browser compatible, so it makes it available to every browser. So `event.preventDefault()` *should* work. Are you sure you are passing the `event` object to the `submit` handler?

Comment: Note that when you have runtime error in the `submit` event the form will be submitted as the `return false` will never be reached.. make sure you don't get such error.

Comment: post your full code of `$('form').submit(function ...` and we'll try to see what might be the problem.

Comment: The rule is to call `event.preventDefault()` as early as possible. Due to the reason @Shadow explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It does work: http://jsfiddle.net/AEC2U/
2. The problem is somewhere else in your code.
3. Post more code/stripped down example where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`return false` is equal to `event.returnValue`

But sometimes this does not work because of DOM compatibility

For Example:

```
// Not Working
OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to Delete this file?');"

// Working
OnClientClick="event.returnValue=confirm('Are you sure want to Delete this file?');"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        alert( 'test' )        
        return false;
    });
});
```

This works for me no problem in IE8.  If anything all I did was get rid of the two passed event variables