# JS - Attaching an event listener with return

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, return

I routinely use the following JavaScript function to attach events to elements in the DOM.

```
function addEventHandler(elem,eventType,handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener (eventType,handler,false);
     }
    else if (elem.attachEvent){
        elem.attachEvent ('on'+eventType,handler); 
    }
}
```

I would like to use it in the following context to attach some AJAX to a form element onsubmit, and then return false so the form is not actually submitted..

```
var elemnt = document.getElementById('myForm');
addEventHandler(elemnt, 'submit', function(){
    // Do stuff
    return false;
});
```

In the past I would attach a event handler like so: `onsubmit="return myfunction();"` but I cannot figure out how to get that `return` in there when attaching event handlers so my function can stop the form from being submitted with JavaScript.

How is this done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950179/javascript-return-false-not-stopping-form-submission. Try event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myForm');
if (element.addEventListener) {
    element.addEventListener('submit', myEventHandler);
}
else {
    element.attachEvent('onclick', myEventHandler);
}

function myEventHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do stuff
}
```

**Update**
`event.preventDefault()` prevents the normal processing of the event after the method in which it is invoked. 
It won't prevent the other event listeners to be executed (use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` to do that), but it will cancel the default effect of the event. So in this case it should prevent the form to be submitted.

**Update 2**
The JavaScript engine will invoke the event listener (your function) and pass it an event object describing the event: its type, the object that is the target of the event...

A detailed explanation about event listeners is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: code-only answers are generally discouraged. can you post some explanation as to how this fixes the problem? thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I checked the w3c and moz. developers and cannot figure out where the `event` object is coming from? care to enlighten me?

Comment: hum... I'm afraid I answered a bit too quickly... sorry, I'll fix this