# How to prevent default event handling in an onclick method?

Tags: javascript

How to prevent default in an onclick method? I have a method in which I am also passing a custom value

```
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

```
function callmymethod(myVal){
    //doing custom things with myVal
    //here I want to prevent default
}
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Let your callback return `false` and pass that on to the `onclick` handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return callmymethod(24)">Call</a>

function callmymethod(myVal){
    //doing custom things with myVal
    //here I want to prevent default
    return false;
}
```

---

To create *maintainable* code, however, you should abstain from using *"inline Javascript"* (i.e.: code that's directly within an element's tag) and modify an element's behavior via an included Javascript source file (it's called [unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

The mark-up:

```
<a href="#" id="myAnchor">Call</a>
```

The code (separate file):

```
// Code example using Prototype JS API
$('myAnchor').observe('click', function(event) {
    Event.stop(event); // suppress default click behavior, cancel the event
    /* your onclick code goes here */
});
```

Comment: @AamirAfridi Yes, it is working. You should adjust your fiddle and change `onLoaded` to `no wrap`. Or simply write your own .html markup instead.

Comment: Please see answer below!

"In my opinion the answer is wrong! He asked for event.preventDefault(); when you simply return false; it calls event.preventDefault(); AND event.stopPropagation(); as well!"

Comment: To be fastidious, the OP's question never mentions `preventDefault`, the question is, how to *"prevent [the] default click"*.

Comment: @LinusKleen, say also please, how to prevent click in this [case](http://jsfiddle.net/9JvdG/)

Comment: @vp_arth Use "CSS click through" for this. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements).

Comment: @LinusKleen, thanks, but I need to stop parent event, when for child own event binded; I already found `stopImmediatePropogation` method for this

Comment: извините, that won't work. That method you found won't work. Since you're using inline event handlers. Would they have been dynamically declared, it might just work.

Comment: I upvoted this because of the warning about maintainable code. This creates problems when you want to use `preventDefault` later.

Comment: "abstain from using inline Javascript", is not always applicable and there are many different frameworks (ie Angular) where inline javascript calls are very important to the flow of the application.

Answer (score 69):

In my opinion the answer is wrong! He asked for `event.preventDefault();` when you simply return false; it calls `event.preventDefault();` AND `event.stopPropagation();` as well!

You can solve it by this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(event, 24)">Call</a>
```

```
function callmymethod(e, myVal){
    //doing custom things with myVal

    //here I want to prevent default
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: You're relying on `window.event` which isn't always available across browsers.

Comment: Edited to add:  event = event  || window.event;

Comment: Just as @LinusKleen said, the window.event is getting deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/window/event

Comment: Actually the original answer(without `e = e || window.event`) is NOT relying on `window.event`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes#event_handler_attributes

Comment: I agree, the accepted answer from Linus may work in some circumstances, but I couldn't get it to work using inline JS.  My application dynamically creates and removes thousands of elements which need JS actions tied to them, so inline JS is really the best way of managing this without trying to manage thousands of event listeners dynamically.  This method of passing the event to the function and then preventing propagation and defaults worked really well.

Answer (score 58):

Try this (but please use buttons for such cases if you don't have a valid `href` value for [graceful degradation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement#Graceful_degradation_and_progressive_enhancement_in_a_nutshell))

```
<a href="#" onclick="callmymethod(24); return false;">Call</a>
```

Comment: nice simply best. I want same this for      event.preventDefault();

Comment: It worked for me, but could you explain why you have to `return false;`? What are we even returning false to?

Comment: you can just return instead of return false, returning will avoid link navigating to href. Technically we should use button for such cases.

Answer (score 15):

You can catch the event and then block it with preventDefault() -- works with pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById("xyz").addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.getAttribute("href"));
    /* Do some other things*/
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Just place "javascript:void(0)", in place of "#" in href tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="callmymethod(24); return false;">Call</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-stoppropagation

Answer (score 7):

Another way to do that is to use the `event` object inside the attribute `onclick` (without the need to add an additional argument to the function to pass the event)

```js
function callmymethod(myVal){
    console.log(myVal);
}
```

```html
<a href="#link" onclick="event.preventDefault();callmymethod(24)">Call</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Several different answers. Even after so many years, the question is still relevant. Therefore, here is the compilation:

```js
// 1
function myFn1 (e, value) {
    console.log('value:', value)
    e.preventDefault();
}

// 2
function myFn2 (value) {
    console.log('value:', value)
    return false;
}

// 3,5,6,7
function myFn3 (value) {
    console.log('value:', value)    
}

// 4
document.getElementById("clicki-1").addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('value:',this.getAttribute("data-value"));
});
```

```html
<h3>onclick Attribute</h3>
<div>
  <a href="/hello" onclick="myFn1(event, 42)">Click 1</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="/hello" onclick="return myFn2(42)">Click 2</a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="/hello" onclick="myFn3(42); return false;">Click 3</a>
</div>

<h3>EventListener (addEventListener)</h3>
<div>
  <a href="/hello" id="clicki-1" data-value="42">Click 4</a>
</div>

<h3>onclick Attribute without linkaddress when hovering</h3>
<div>  
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="event.preventDefault(); myFn3(42)">Click 5</a>
</div>

<div>  
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFn3(42)">Click 6</a>
</div>

<div>  
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFn3(42)">Click 7</a>
</div>

<h5>Set Anchor Hashtag</h5>
<div>  
  <a href="#" onclick="myFn3(42)">Click 8</a>
</div>
```

I prefer the variant 2 with return false; if it has to go quickly. And otherwise variant 4 (AddEventListener).

Answer (score 1):

It would be too tedious to alter function usages in all html pages to `return false`.

So here is a tested solution that patches only the function itself:

```
function callmymethod(myVal) {
    // doing custom things with myVal

    // cancel default event action
    var event = window.event || callmymethod.caller.arguments[0];
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);

    return false;
}
```

This correctly prevents IE6, IE11 and latest Chrome from visiting `href="#"` after onclick event handler completes.

Credits:

- [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)
- [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to put it in the tag. Not the finest solution, but it will work.

Make sure you put the onclick event in front of the href. Only worked for my this way.

```
<a onclick="return false;" href="//www.google.de">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a form instead of a link. Then, all you really need to do is add:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
```

You probably want to handle it though so in total you'd probably do something more like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to ...? This action cannot be undone.")) {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/test" id="myForm">
  <input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();myFunction();">
</form>
```

This allows the user to click ok to proceed or cancel to not have it submit the form.

Answer (score -3):

Give a class or id to the element and use jquery function unbind();

```
$(".slide_prevent").click(function(){
                $(".slide_prevent").unbind();
              });
```