# Click Element isn't showing/hiding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my code, I'm trying to create a function to hide and show a div
and it's working, but it dosnt work at first, It works only on the second click, so i have to click the link first to get it to start working properly, how can i fix it so that it works on first click?

more info:

im trying to have a div appear and then disapear usin the display and hide functions, the catch is i also want it to disapper when im outside of the div, if its visible, its all working but the problem is when i first load the page thn click the link to display the div, it dosnt appear, only when i click it a second time does it appear. this is the problem i want to fix

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="js/jquery.foggy.min.js"></script>    


    <style>

        body {
            background: black;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-position: center;
            background-size: 100%;
            color: white;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI';
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        .box 
        {
            width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
            top: 0px;
            left: 20%;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: white;
            opacity: 0.4;
            position: fixed;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            overflow-x: scroll;
        }

    </style>


  </head>
  <body>

    <script lang="en" type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {


        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {

            var container = $("#boxwrapper");

            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                if (container.is(':visible'))
                    Hide();
            }
        });

        function Display() {
            $("#boxwrapper").show();
            $("#boxwrapper").addClass("box");
            $("#main").foggy();
        }

        function Hide() {
            $("#boxwrapper").hide();
            $("#main").foggy(false);
        }
    </script>



        <div id="main">
               <a href="#" onclick="Display()">Display Div</a>
        </div>

        <div id="boxwrapper">
        </div>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"so i have to click the link first to get it to start working properly, how can i fix it so that it works on first click":* - first click on what..?

Comment: @TJ what does that jsfiddle demonstrate? It doesn't seem to do anything. *edit* oh wait I see.

Comment: @Pointy Well you were right first. I thought clicking the link first time isn't showing the div... I'm not sure what else OP wants to click.. 0__0

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why you need to use the mouseup on the document?

Comment: im trying to have a div appear and then disapear usin the display and hide functions, the catch is i also want it to disapper when im outside of the div, if its visible, its all working but the problem is when i first load the page thn click the link to display the div, it dosnt appear, only when i click it a second time does it appear. this is the problem i want to fix

Comment: mmm... I don't see the old `e.preventDefault()` or return false in the link `onClick()` event ;)

Comment: *"when i first load the page thn click the link to display the div, it dosnt appear"* - [Unable To Reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/o7d17w4w/). Try to reproduce the issue in that fiddle.

Comment: here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e8hj27gf/21/

I have it working but i need it to work using one toggle Link,

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use `click()` method insead of `mouseup()`?

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#boxwrapper");
    if (container.is(':visible')) {
        Hide();
    } else {
        Display();
    }
    return false;
});
```

If you don't want to bind this event to every `<a>` on your site, add class to your element and bind click to this class. E.g.:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Display()" class="divToggle">Display Div</a>
```

and then in your script:

```
$('a.divToggle').click(function (e) { });
```

Comment: thanks i will organize the code, i can make it toggle on and off but i want the div to hide when the user clicks outside of it anywhere as well, that's why the use of mouseup

Comment: So use `$('html, body')` istead of `$('a')` and it also should work.

Comment: i put this together but it dosnt seem to do what i was after,

Comment: What's wrong with using `mouseup`? how'll using `click()` method instead will fix OP's issue?

Answer (score -1):

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9k4re1d2/1/)

#### JavaScript

```js
function display() {
    if ($('#boxwrapper ').css('display') === 'none') {
        $('#boxwrapper').show();
    } else {
        $('#boxwrapper').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: All this is the same that `$('#boxwrapper').toggle();`

Comment: Can you explain why this will fix OP's problem?

Comment: display is passed as argument for onclick. Triggering this function the div will display and vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be a whitespace or anything, since is very hard to reproduce it, but here some advices or things that could be causing the issue:

#### Organize your code

- First of all, you need to organize your code and load the JS libraries at the end of the file or wrap your functions inside the `$(document).ready`.
- If you are using jQuery already, why to use the onClick event on the element itself if you can do it with jQuery.
- Instead of all code inside the document mouseUp event, you could just add `display: none` in the css to `#boxwrapper`.
- Instead of `Hide()` and `Show()` functions, you could just use [`toogleClass('box')` jquery function](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

#### Difference between Click and MouseUp events

With a mouseup event, you can click somewhere else on the screen, hold down the click button, and move the pointer to your mouseup element, and then release the mouse pointer. A click event requires the mousedown and mouseup event to happen on that element.

#### Prevent Default Maybe?

You are not [preventing Default on your click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/prevent-default-event-in-onclick). You can do it like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Display(); return false;">Display Div</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question or solve the issue. [Becuase there is no issue](http://jsfiddle.net/o7d17w4w/) none of the stuff you're talking about is applicable in this case.

Comment: @TJ: I know that this is not an answer, but we are trying to dig around the problem, since is very hard to reproduce it. Could be a white space or any other thing. There is no need to downvote the answers.

Comment: 1) *I know that this is not an answer*. 2) From your answer: **The real Problem: Prevent Default**. from your comment: *Could be a white space or any other thing*. Hence the downvote. `P.S` : *trying to dig around the problem* is not an answer. You can do that in comments. By the way, like i said none of the things you mentioned above is applicable here. the downvote tooltip reads: *"this answer is not useful"*