# Prevent default is not working in my case

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this form which is used for posting message whose js file is as follows. I want to prevent default action of the form and submit using ajax ::::

```js
function iFrameOn()
{
 richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
}
function iBold()
{
 richTextField.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
 
}
function iItalic()
{
 richTextField.document.execCommand('italic',false,null);
 
}

function iLink()
{
 var linkURL = prompt('Enter the URL for this link:','http://');
 richTextField.document.execCommand('CreateLink',false,linkURL);
 
}

 
function submit_form(){
  var theForm = document.getElementById('myform');
  theForm.elements["message"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
  
  $('#myform').submit();
  
  $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var formData = new FormData(this);
   console.log($('#myform').attr('action'));
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data:formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(data){
     console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data){
     console.log("error");
     console.log(data);
    }
   });
  });
 }
 else
  alert("Your message is empty");
}
```

```html
**THE FORM IS**
<form method="POST" action="dmessage3.php" name="myform" id="myform" class="form1" >  
<textarea name="message" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14" style="display:none;"></textarea>
<iframe name="richTextField" id="richTextField"  ></iframe>

<div id="toolbar" class="toolbar">
<input type="button" onClick="iBold()" value="B" class="tools" >
<input type="button" onClick="iItalic()" value="I" class="tools">
<input type="button" onClick="iLink()" value="Link" class="tools">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="id1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="id2" value="2">
<input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit data" onClick="javascript:submit_form();">
</form>
```

But the form is not posting using ajax

Comment: Comment this //$('#myform').submit();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `e.preventDefault()`, you'll need to use it in a jQuery `.on()` kind of call.  Not on an `onClick` in the html.  Or, if you're going to use the onclick in your html, then you'll need to add a `return false;` at the end of that function.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/prevent-default-event-in-onclick) is a link if you want to know more about this.

Here is a version that should work for you (depending on which jQuery version you're using).  I wasn't sure what the `else {}` clause at the end of your `submit_form()` function was for, but I removed it (an `else-clause` needs an `if-clause` preceding it to be valid).

```
function submit_form(){
    var theForm = document.getElementById('myform');
    theForm.elements["message"].value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;

    var formData = new FormData(this);
    console.log($('#myform').attr('action'));
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submit_form();
});
```

And with this code, just remove the onClick attribute from your html-form button, like so:

```
<input name="myBtn" type="button" value="Submit data" />
```

And also make sure you have either a closing tag to all your html tags that need a closing tag, or add a `/` at the end of your tag like the line above to make it a self-closing tag.

Comment: The code is working fine with textarea but with iframe it's not responding...Please suggest something

Comment: What use is your iframe inside the form?  Can you take it outside the form html-tags?

Comment: An iFrame is essentially a window to another browser session.  The contents of the iFrame are not actually inside your page, therefore you cannot submit them as part of a form.

Comment: I have put the contents of iframe in textarea  /// theForm.elements["message"].value=window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;    ///// It's like important to use iframe coz i have made text editor

Comment: Can you put the iFrame above the `<form></form>` tags?  It's technically not part of the form, except in your javascript.