# How to use onclcik and href in anchor tag and make only onclick work.href is only for google crawling

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, anchor, href

In my website when i click on images it opens new page using onclcik openpopup(user defined function)

my problem is google will not index onclcik urls,it only index href urls.

So i want to use use onclcik and href in anchor tag  and make only onclick work.href is only for Google crawling purpose only my code is as below

```
var imgurl = "http:"+lcurl+touch_id+".jpg";
                 var data = "<div id=charm_"+touch_id+" data-charmid="+touch_id+" data-vis="+bgid+" data-vid="+seid+" data-vtitle="+vtitle_url+" data-title="+title_url+" style='float:left;' class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col charm-wrapper'>\n\
                <div class='mdl-card-wrapper charm-inner'>\n\
                  <div class='demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--8dp'>\n\
                        <div class='mdl-card__media'>\n\
                        "+locicon+" \n\
                      <a href="popupurl" id='myAnchor' > \n\
                      <div style='position:relative;'>\n\
                      <div style='position:absolute;z-index:9;right:0px;bottom:0px;'><img width=32px src="+cf_assets+"img/hanger.png></div>\n\
                       <div id=imagearea_"+touch_id+" title='"+title+"' class='imagearea loading'>\n\
                      </div></div></a>\n\
                    </div>\n\
                          <div class='mdl-card__title'>\n\
                    <div class='right-charm'>\n\
                     <div class='social-share'>\n\
                     "+copycontent+"\n\
                     "+watsapp+"\n\
                          <a onclick=sharetofb('"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"'); title='Facebook' id=fb"+touch_id+" \n\
                  class='fb_share'></a>\n\
                <a onclick=sharetotwitter('"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"'); title='Twitter' id=tw"+touch_id+" class='tw_share'> </a>\n\
                          </div>\n\
                          </div>\n\
                          <div class='icharm'>\n\
                      <h2 class='mdl-card__title-text'>"+subtitle+"</h2>\n\
                      <div class='mdl-card__subtitle-text'>"+title+"</div>\n\
                      <div id=vid_"+touch_id+" class='mdl-card__subtitle-videoname'>"+videoname+"</div>\n\
                       </div>\n\
                        </div>\n\
                      </div>\n\
                  </div>\n\
                </div>";
      $('#main-home-page-inner').add(HTML(data));


          callcloudinary(imgurl,title,touch_id);
          callmasonry();

      if(i == setarr.length-1){


         localStorage.touchids=touchid_arr.join(",");
        localStorage.searchresults=gcharmarr.join(",");
     }
     // document.getElementById("main-home-page-inner").innerHTML += html;

    }

    /* document.getElementById("fb"+touch_id).setAttribute("onclick","sharetofb('"+title+"','"+text+"','"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"','"+social_domain+lcurl+touch_id+".jpg')");*/
  }
   //addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
       //ev.preventDefault();
       // alert(ev.target.getAttribute("data-charmid"));
     // openpopup(ev.target.getAttribute("data-url"));
     // sendpym(ev.target.getAttribute("data-title"));
   // });
            $('myAnchor').on('click',function(ev){ 
 ev.preventDefault();
 openpopup(ev.target.getAttribute("popupurl"));
      sendpym(ev.target.getAttribute("data-charmid"));
```

});

```
           })
           .error(function(status, statusText, responseText) {
                //console.log(statusText);
                //console.log(responseText);
           });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) Please don't post code in comments, use the `edit` function to add it to the question. Look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance

Comment: @sudankanakavel Post you developer console log

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code. Place the elements in quotes. Work correctly with quotes.

```
    var imgurl = "http:"+lcurl+touch_id+".jpg";
    var data = "<div id='charm_"+touch_id+"' data-charmid='"+touch_id+"' data-vis='"+bgid+"' data-vid='"+seid+"' data-vtitle='"+vtitle_url+"' data-title='"+title_url+"' style='float:left;' class='mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col charm-wrapper'><div class='mdl-card-wrapper charm-inner'><div class='demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--8dp'><div class='mdl-card__media'>"+locicon+"<a href='"+popupurl+"' id='myAnchor' ><div style='position:relative;'><div style='position:absolute;z-index:9;right:0px;bottom:0px;'><img width='32px' src='"+cf_assets+"img/hanger.png'></div><div id='imagearea_"+touch_id+"' title='"+title+"' class='imagearea loading'></div></div></a></div><div class='mdl-card__title'><div class='right-charm'><div class='social-share'>"+copycontent+""+watsapp+"<a onclick='sharetofb(\'"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"\');' title='Facebook' id='fb"+touch_id+"' class='fb_share'></a><a onclick='sharetotwitter(\'"+ct_domain+socialshare_url+"\');' title='Twitter' id='tw"+touch_id+"' class='tw_share'></a></div></div><div class='icharm'><h2 class='mdl-card__title-text'>"+subtitle+"</h2><div class='mdl-card__subtitle-text'>"+title+"</div><div id='vid_"+touch_id+"' class='mdl-card__subtitle-videoname'>"+videoname+"</div></div></div></div></div></div>";

    $('#main-home-page-inner').add(HTML(data));
    callcloudinary(imgurl,title,touch_id);
    callmasonry();

    if(i == setarr.length-1)
    {
        localStorage.touchids=touchid_arr.join(",");
        localStorage.searchresults=gcharmarr.join(",");
    }
    }
} // WHY????

$('myAnchor').on('click',function(ev){ 
ev.preventDefault();
openpopup(ev.target.getAttribute("popupurl"));
sendpym(ev.target.getAttribute("data-charmid"));
```

> See how to properly use the quotes `'` and `"`in a variable in
>   [w3schools.com - JavaScript
>   Strings](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by returning false from the handler function at the end.

[Refer to this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/prevent-default-event-in-onclick)

Also, you can use something like this if you are using JQuery:

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){ 
     e.preventDefault();
     // Do your other stuff.
});
```

In this example I am targeting your anchor tag by tagname. Add a class or ID instead.

Comment: I  get the following error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null. popup window opens but no content in it.kindly help

Comment: hi behnam bozorg i followed the instruction but still i get the error unexpected identifier

Comment: is it possible to solve this problem using core javascript alone. I don't want to use jquery

Comment: if  any solution using minified.js /core javascript/html also will do for me

Comment: is it possible to apply the changes for all the anchor tags.

Comment: Hi, Yes is it possible to do this by JS alone. JQuery is just a collection of wrapping functions around native JS functionalities.

Comment: Also, you are getting unexpected identifier for another reason. maybe a missing character, parenthesise etc. you should Target your element correctly. assign a class or ID and target it with JQuery or native JS,