# How to prevent refresh on submit but also actually submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I've seen many stack overflow posts telling the user to prevent the page refresh by using return false or by changing the input type to button, but this works by disabling submission, which I need. How do I keep submission of my form enabled using my button, without refreshing the page upon use?

EDIT: this post is entirely different from the supposed duplicate. That post is is only concerned with submission of the form, whereas the crux of this post is submission without page refresh

Comment: um, if you need to submit the form, the page is going to submit... Are you making an Ajax call in place of it?

Comment: use ajax and do your own form serialization.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/prevent-default-event-in-onclick

Comment: As I said in the original post, this doesn't work for me because I need to form to actually submit, which returning false prevents

Answer (score 1):

you can submit a form using the .submit() function in jquery

```
$('#your-id-form').submit( function(e) { 
   //prevent submit
   e.preventDefault(); //Thx @alex

   //do things on submit
   $.ajax({
       data: "data",
       type: "POST",
       url: "your-destiny.php",
       beforeSend: function(){
        //before send data
       },
       success: function(data){
           // the data
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
 });
```

Cheers,