# Save HTML user input to Javascript variables

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert

I'm testing the waters with HTML/CSS/Javascript.  I have a (moderately) firm grasp of the three languages separately, it's just trying to get them to cooperate with each other that is giving me issues.

My CSS and Javascript files are linked externally to my HTML file.

I'm trying to get Javascript to save user input in a variable and show the text in an alert window.

```js
function saveUn() {
  var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
  alert(username);
}
```

```html
<form>
  Username:
  <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="saveUn();" />
</form>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: It turns out my problem was, in fact, that I didn't insert my external Javascript file correctly.  I fixed it, and now my code works just fine.  Typos ruin lives, kids.

Comment: Try preventDefault to prevent submitting your form.

Comment: Try putting saveUn(); function on onSubmit event of the form(instead of onClick of button) with "return false" (in the function body) if you want just want to display an alert.

Comment: I don't see the problem, this works fine in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/2ovdsgac/

Answer (score 2):

try with `event.preventDefault();`

```js
function saveUn(event) {
  var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
  alert(username);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form>
  Username:
  <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="saveUn(event);" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let your callback `return` false and pass that on to the `onclick` handler:

```
<form>
    Username:
    <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return saveUn();" />
</form>

function saveUn() {
    var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
    alert(username);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **Code** that might help you.

```js
    
    document.getElementById("clickHere").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
    alert(username);
});
```

```html
<form >
        Username:
        <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
        <input type="submit" id="clickHere" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you do not want to submit the form and just want display an `alert`:

```
<form onSubmit = "return saveUn();">
    Username:
    <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
function saveUn() {
    var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
    alert(username);
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return boolean value for `saveUn()`, `return false` if you do not want to submit

```js
function saveUn() {
  var username = document.getElementById('un').value;
  alert(username);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Username:
  <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
  <input type="submit" onclick="return saveUn();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6 this should be better:

```
<form >
    Username:
    <input type="text" size="12" id="un" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="clickHere" />
</form>   

 const smBtn = document.querySelector("clickHere");
 smBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    let username = document.querySelector('un').value;
    alert(username);
});
```