# How to retrieve information from an element in Javascript when onclick is triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Let's say I have a *link* in my DOM (but any element would be accepted), with a call to a Javascript function :

```
<a href="google.com" onclick="myFunction()">
```

, and a Jquery function to replace the click on that link and retrieve its `href` attribute *(sorry, I'm working in Jquery, but feel free to answer in vanilla JS)* :

```
function myFunction() {
    $(this).click(function() { return false; }); // Cancel normal behavior.
    console.log($(this).attr("href"));
}
```

This actually doesn't work. Usually, we need to **point** to an element's **ID** or **Class** to get its informations ; **but if we can't set** an ID or Class or anything and just process some links in a page, how to **directly retrieve their informations** ?

The title of this topic is intentionally general, because the method should be working for any HTML element.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're actually preventing the normal behaviour only once the element has been clicked.  What is your actual question, because it's not clear? Are you asking how to override the `myFunction` function, or are you asking how to bind to a specific DOM element that doesn't have a class or ID?

Comment: `<a href="google.com" onclick="myFunction()">`

Comment: @BenM My question is very clear : I want to retrive informations from an element that hasn't an ID or Class. The fact that I want to prevent the link normal's behavior is just a secondary issue (wich is understandable, given that cliking on a link will reach the target, and I don't want that).

Comment: do you have to use onclick inline attributes? its bad practice.

Comment: Yes I have to , due to the logic of the script I want to conceive (it's supposed to edit links in a page, in order to open a popup with the href). But anyway, someone gave me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are right that with id or css selector you could do. But there is another way.

Just pass **this** while calling function and then you can access all attributes of the element like below :

```
<a href="google.com"  style="background-color: yellow" onclick="myFunction(this, event)"> click me !!!! <a>
```

then you can access all info like below :

```
 function myFunction(element, event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // event object can be passed
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red" // attribute can be accessed
    console.log(element.attributes["data-name"])

}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't test your code given that preventDefault() doesn't work to stop the link to open a new page.

Comment: you said for any element. so i did demo with DIV element. Its works fine. DO you want with link element only???

Comment: Yeah, I'm not supposed to know that suddently, my technic for avoiding the link to redirect will fail, and that all code proposed by everybody will fail too. I was thinking that I could ask a general question, but it seems that I need to do a new topic about LINKS only, due to the amount of shit that JS is bringing me in.

Comment: Okey. I have updated my answer using link tag. Please verify

Answer (score 1):

You can access clicked element as below

`<a href="https://google.com" onclick="myFunction(this)">`

```
function myFunction(that) {
    console.log(that.href);
}
```

Comment: Why use jQuery *only* to get the attribute? Just `this.href` will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

HTML `<a href="#" onclick="myFunction(event)">click</a>`

JS

```
function myFunction(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Do your stuff with event.target which is <a>
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work you could use `event.target.href`?

Comment: event.prevendDefault(); doesn't work :
```
function myFunction(element) {
 //$(element).click(function() { return false; });
 element.preventDefault();
    console.log(element.attributes["href"]);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't stop the link to open a page.

Comment: Did you pass arg `onclick="myFunction(event)"`?

Comment: You could try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method/7056673

Comment: @SonjoySamadder He wants example using link  and wants to serve both purpose. prevent the click actions and accessing attributes . I have given the answer which marked. Could you please vote the answer

Comment: Erratum :  I was using "myFunction(element)" and "element.preventDefault();". I didn't know that we had to use specific keywords like "event" for it to work. So, I retract my last comment.

Comment: Okay then first why not

`event.preventDefault()`
`// Do your stuff`
`window.location.href = event.target.href; // To go to the link.`