# JS onClick preventDefault for Input

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

How can I prevent the default onClick behavior for an `<input>`?

```js
document.getElementById("main").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  If you click here, change background to red.
  <input id="search" type="search" value="If you click here, do nothing.">
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7bng6zuh/3/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent default event handling in an onclick method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method)

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent your div from changing it's background when the input is clicked and only change it when the div is directly clicked, just compare the event **target** with the event **current target** (the element you added the click listener to) and change the div css only if the target is the same as the current target like this:

```js
const mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");

function checkClick(e) {
 if (e.target === e.currentTarget) { // check if element clicked is the div itself or some other element in the div.
   mainDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

mainDiv.addEventListener('click', checkClick);
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  If you click here, change background to red. 
  <input id="search" type="search" value="If you click here, do nothing.">
</div>
```

---

**Event Target:** The element you clicked.

**Event Current Target:** The element that the click listener is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target:

```js
document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  if (e.target.id && e.target.id  === "main") { // or e.target === e.currentTarget
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  If you click here, change background to red. 
  <input id="search" type="search" value="If you click here, do nothing.">
</div>
```