# when I click the button to open the sidebar it brings a blank white page

Tags: javascript, html, css

This a project from school that I've been working on but I'm facing some obstacles in the Sidebar button at the top left corner. The button is opening and showing a blank white page can someone help me out?

```js
function open() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "relative";
}

function close() {
  document.getElementById("sidebar").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #3c1642;
  justify-self: left;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navBar" class="menuBar">
  <button onclick="open()" style="border: 0px; background-color: #272640;">
      <div class="menuBar" >
          <div class="menu-inner">
          <span class="bar bar-1" id="br1"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-2" id="br2"></span>
          <span class="bar bar-3" id="br3"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </button>

  <div class="menuOptions" style="flex-grow: 5; border-right: 0px; align-self: left;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="head" class="menuOptions" style="flex-grow: 3; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; align-self: center; 
                justify-content: center; position: relative;">
    <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color: #f72585; ">WD BOOTCAMP</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menuOptions" style="flex-grow: 3; justify-content: end; border-left: 0px; align-self: right; ">
    <a class="menuBut" style=" border: 3px solid #f72585; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;"></a>
    <a class="menuBut"></a>
    
    <form action="" style="display: flex; justify-self: end; height: 30%; margin-top: 30px;">
      <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="search">
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar">
  <button onclick="close()">Close X</button>
  <a href="">link1</a>
  <a href="">link2</a>
  <a href="">link3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not an on demand help site. Please post the code you have and describe the problem you have.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to put the code in sorry I edited it

Comment: `relative` is not an allowed value for the `display` property.

Comment: Are you referring to the `WD BOOTCAMP` link? What are you expecting to happen? My guess is that you want to [prevent the default click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056669/how-to-prevent-default-event-handling-in-an-onclick-method) instead of opening a blank link?

Comment: I tried putting in **block** but It didn't help

Comment: You haven't specified a `type` for your button, so it's acting as a `type="submit"`. Add `type="button"` to prevent the default submit behavior.

Comment: I tried **type** but it still shows a blank white page

Comment: And you should name your functions differently. In the global scope, they are properties of the window object - but `window.open` and `window.close` exist as methods already, so this is likely to conflict.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, that's why I habitually use the `preventDefault()` command just in case

Comment: You've also created your CSS selector as an `id` selector, which is difficult to override. Use a CSS class and class selector instead.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan ??? That's really not a great way to work. Use the right HTML for the job and you won't need JavaScript patches.

Comment: I changed the function name to **SidebarOpen & SidebarClose** and now the button isn't working

Comment: @ScottMarcus - I mostly use ASP so it's not usually pure HTML, plus a lot of elements tend to be created dynamically through jQuery, so `preventDefault` saves me the grief of having to hunt down wherever the guy who made the button put it.

Comment: Also, @SahilShrivastava, why've you got a menu bar within a button? Can't imagine that looking nice

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan I dunno what else should I put it in, I've tried putting it in hyperlink but It's still ugly

Comment: @SahilShrivastava sometimes it's better for a thing to not be in things

Comment: but then how would it act like a button and have the animation effect that I want it to have

Answer (score 0):

You have several things that need attention, but the primary two are:

- You aren't specifying `type="button"` on your `button` elements, so
  they default to acting like `type="submit"` and cause your form to
  submit, but your form doesn't have a path for the `action`, so you
  just get a blank page.
- Unless you will be submitting data to another location, you shouldn't
  even have a `form` element in the first place.

Beyond that, you should avoid inline styles whenever possible because they are the hardest styles to override and they lead to duplication of code and clutter up the code in general.

Avoid inline event attributes as well and hook up your elements to events in JavaScript with `.addEventListener()`.

```js
const sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebar");

sidebar.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  sidebar.classList.add("hidden");
});

document.querySelector("button.butStyle1").addEventListener("click", function(){
    sidebar.classList.remove("hidden");
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: #3c1642;
  justify-self: left;
}

/* Put styles that might need to be added/removed
   in separate classes so that just that property
   can be adjusted as needed.  */
.hidden { display: none; }

/* Avoid inline styles whenever possible */
.menuOptions {
  flex-grow: 3; 
  border-left: 0px; 
  border-right: 0px; 
  position: relative;
}

.flexStyles1 {
  align-self: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}

.flexStyles2 {
  align-self: right; 
  justify-content: end; 
}

.butStyle1 { border: 0px; background-color: #e0e0e0; }

.form { display: flex; justify-self: end; height: 30%; margin-top: 30px; }
```

```html
<nav id="navBar" class="menuBar">
  <button type="button" class="butStyle1">
      <div class="menuBar" >
          <div class="menu-inner">
            <span class="bar bar-1" id="br1">x</span>
            <span class="bar bar-2" id="br2">y</span>
            <span class="bar bar-3" id="br3">z</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </button>

  <div class="menuOptions" style="flex-grow: 5; border-right: 0px; align-self: left;">
  </div>
  
  <div id="head" class="menuOptions flexStyles1">
    <a href="" style="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color: #f72585; ">WD BOOTCAMP</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menuOptions flexStyles2">
    <a class="menuBut" style=" border: 3px solid #f72585; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 0px;"></a>
    <a class="menuBut"></a>
    

      <input type="text" id="searchBar" placeholder="search">

  </div>
</nav>

<div id="sidebar" class="hidden">
  <button type="button">Close X</button>
  <a href="">link1</a>
  <a href="">link2</a>
  <a href="">link3</a>
</div>
```