# Why isn't my callback function for this Jquery .post working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .post

Here is the code for the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#room').submit(function(){
            $.post('backend/CreateRoom.php', $('#room').serialize() ,function(data) {
                alert(1);
                $('#llama').append(data);
                console.log('working');
            });
        });
        return false;
     }); 
</script>
```

The function part does not seem to be working. The PHP code on the backend/CreateRoom.php seems to work fine(the code updates a PHP database) works fine, it just doesnt update the div, or do anything I put in the function. Help?

Comment: What does the server respond with? `200 OK` ?

Comment: Do you see the message with "1" on the screen?

Comment: try adding .error(function() { alert("error"); }) at the end of you $.post statement. Look for "error" on [jquery post API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and you should be able to debug it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are returning `false` on document ready. I think you want that on submit.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#room').submit(function(){
        $.post('backend/CreateRoom.php', $('#room').serialize() ,function(data) {
            alert(1);
            $('#llama').append(data);
            console.log('working');
        });
     return false;
    });

});
```

or prevent default:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#room').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('backend/CreateRoom.php', $('#room').serialize() ,function(data) {
            alert(1);
            $('#llama').append(data);
            console.log('working');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Dont forget `e.returnValue = false;` for IE7/8

Comment: @stevether Thanks. News to me. It may just be mootools, still looking for jquery example. For my example it's `event.returnValue = false` and further explanation here: [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help)