# javascript working in Firefox or Chrome not IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following lines of code in my `.js` file

```
$(triggers.restart).live('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  plugin.method.startQuiz(this);
});
```

The code is working fine in Firefox or Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. What might be wrong?

Comment: does IE give you any kind of error?

Comment: look into the IE settings, maybe JS is off. If that still doesnt work try on another computer. if it STILL doesn't work, well, it is IE

Comment: How about the rest of the code and/or an example?

Comment: it will be helpful if you give the DOM structure also

Comment: It is pretty impossible to debug this issue without more code. The issue could be a great number of things. Put it in a fiddle if you want a serious answer - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE preventDefault isn't supported. Instead you set the return value. There's more info about it here: [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help)

Comment: He appears to be using jquery, and they normalize prevent default for you already. [reference](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/event-preventdefault-and-ie)