# Unobtrusive JavaScript in links

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, unobtrusive-javascript, graceful-degradation

I want a link to either execute a JavaScript function (if JavaScript is available) or enter the URL in the `href` attribute if it's not.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="example(); return false;">
```

In this example, I'd want to execute `example()` and **not** enter the link if JavaScript is available or go to `http://www.example.com` if JavaScript is unavailable.

While this works in almost every browser I've tried it with, in IE 7, regardless of if JavaScript is active or not, it just follows the link. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This *may* be what you are looking for

event.returnValue = false;

Retrieved from here:
[event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie-any-help)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) on the event object to prevent the default action (that is, navigating to the link's URL).

Because the implementation differes a little bit in browsers, you should write a separate function for doing this and call it in your event handler:

```
function preventDefault(event) {
        if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
}
```

Also, be sure to **return false** in your event handler.

If you're using any JavaScript library, then this functionality is very likely to already be present.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your javascript from HTML :)

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com" id='uniq-link'>
```

```js
$(function () {
    $("#uniq-link").on("click", example);
});
```

If Javascript is unavailable - all will be ok :)

Comment: +1 on this, but OP didn't mention he is using jQuery or any other library

Comment: And it's time to do that :) if it is not :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="example(); event.returnValue=false; return false;">
```