# IE Error with e.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, preventdefault

I apologise in advance if this has already been covered but I’m new to this, I have seen there are other similar posts but none of them have helped so I am thinking there might be another issue.

I have a modal popup and it works fine in Chrome but doesn’t work in IE.  The problem appears to be with the line

```
{ e.preventDefault(); }
```

It gives the following error.

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'

Like I said I am new to this and I’ve tried doing what it says in other logs by putting an if round it or just removing the line but with no luck so could anyone help me.

```
/* prevent default behaviour on click */
var e = this.browserEvent;
var tgt = this.triggeringElement;
/*e.preventDefault();*/
{ e.preventDefault(); }
/* Trigger JQuery UI dialog */
var horizontalPadding = 30;
var verticalPadding = 30;
$('<iframe id="modalDialog" src="' + $(tgt).attr("href") + '" />').dialog({
   title: "IC v RT",
   autoOpen: true,
   width: 1050,
   height: 700,
   modal: true,
   close: function(event, ui) {apex.event.trigger('#P28_AFTER_MODAL','select',''); $(this).remove();},
   overlay: {
       opacity: 0.5,
       background: "black"}
}).width(1050 - horizontalPadding).height(700 - verticalPadding);
return false;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE. ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie)

Answer (score 32):

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

from [event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: new Event(event).preventDefault();<br/>
'Event' is undefined<br/>
<br/>
    new Event.preventDefault();<br/>
'Event' is undefined<br/>
<br/>
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();<br/>
Unable to get value of the property 'preventDefault': object is null or undefined<br/>
<br/>
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;<br/>
Unable to get value of the property 'preventDefault': object is null or undefined<br/>
<br/>
    event.returnValue = false;<br/>
Unable to set value of the property 'returnValue': object is null or undefined<br/>

Answer (score 5):

```
if(event.preventDefault) 
{
  event.preventDefault();
}
else
{
   event.returnValue = false;
}
```