# preventdefault() not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, leaflet

I'm working on a page that makes fairly heavy use of ajax. All the ajax forms appear to be working fine across browsers but one final step on the page is broken in IE8 and below.

Here is a demo page showing the problem: http://jolora.com/~fwm/

To reproduce the issue please fill in the final form (email name etc) - a list of markers will be shown on the map. The 'Request Appointment' button should fire an ajax function but instead it actually submits the form in IE7 and IE8 so it appears preventDefault isn't working.

Here's the relevant jQuery:

```
// Request appointment
$('#map').on('submit', 'form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var solicitorID = $(this).attr('id');
    solicitorRequest(solicitorID,applicationID);
});

function solicitorRequest(requestedSolicitor,currentApplication) {
$.ajax({
    url: siteurl + 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data:{
        'action':'do_ajax',
        'fn':'request_solicitor',
        'solicitor': requestedSolicitor,
        'application': currentApplication       
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success:function(data){
        alert('Please check your email - this success function needs improving');
    },
    error: function(errorThrown){
        alert('error');
        //console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

The popups are built using Leaflet's bindPopup method http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup and here's the structure of the content I insert into the popup:

```
var popupContentBegin = '<form id="'
+ solicitor.id + '">'
+ '<h3>' + solicitor.name + '</h3>'
+ '<div class="contact-details">'
+ '<span class="addr">' + solicitor.address + '</span>';

var popupContentTel = '';

if(solicitor.telephone != false) {
    popupContentTel = '<span class="tel">'
    + solicitor.telephone
    + '</span>';
}

var popupContentEnd = '</div>'
+ '<button type="submit">Request appointment</button>'
+ '</form>';

var popupContent = popupContentBegin + popupContentTel + popupContentEnd;

var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {icon: solicitorIcon}).bindPopup(popupContent, popupOptions);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested whether it actually gets into that function to begin with? IE8 could be ignoring that function altogether (and ultimately ignoring the `.preventDefault()`).

Comment: Hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your input. It had crossed my mind that it wasn't even getting that far but I'm not sure how I can check this to be honest.

Comment: @arjuncc - I've updated my code to use returnValue if preventdefault is not available but I don't think this should make a difference as jQuery accounts for it. preventdefault() works fine for the other forms in IE8 and below.

Comment: what? your page getting refreshes everytime you submit.

Comment: Can you explain that your form is dynamically generated or not.

Comment: @Jai - yes, when submitting the "request appointment" form (any of them) inside the dynamically generated leafet map popups. This problem is only in IE8 and below - Chrome and Firefox are working fine.

Comment: I feel like @JamesDonnelly is the closest in suggesting that the function is actually being totally ignored. So it's probably something wrong with my .on() method

Comment: The code doesn't get executed.

Comment: have you tested with `return false;` instead of `.preventDefault()`

Comment: @ZippyV - any idea why not?

Comment: Your selector is probably wrong

Comment: @arjuncc: Since OP is using jQuery, [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is enough - the jQueryEvent object has no `returnValue` at all

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selector to:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#map form', function(event) {...
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

EDIT: You need to call this function inside a ready function so that you can be sure the DOM was completely loaded:

```
$(function () {
  // Put code here
});
```

Comment: I've tried it. It still worked in Chrome but not in IE8. Same problem. Using #map in the selector shouldn't be a problem as it exists originally in the DOM (it's not added later).

Comment: @JoeSpurling Added another possible solution