# <Select> inherits javascript onclick from container and hides options

Tags: php, javascript

I am creating an internal web app for my company, I am having issues with a `javascript` function and `onclick`. The page in question has a dynamic list generated from a Database return.

The *only* issue I am having is that I set up an `onclick` for my list item div containers in which it changes the color to a gray (hover color is the light blue seen below), I recently added a `<select>` drop down to each list item. I set `visibility` to `hidden` for when the item is not selected and `visible` when selected.

My issue is that when trying to select an option the contents disappear because the onclick function is called.

After the div is clicked on the `<Select>` shows properly:
[image]

Here is what happens when clicking on the `<Select>`:
[image]

Here is my code (Please see comments):

```php
// I removed irrelevant styling (floats, don't allow text selection, etc...).
$out .= "<label for='".$i."'>";
$out .= "<div id='".$divId."' class='schListItem'>";
$out .= "<div style='width:25px;'>".$i."</div>";
// Here is my checkbox and onclick javascript function call
$out .= "<div style='width:25px;'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='index[]' id='".$i."' value='".$index."' onclick='selectDiv(this.id);' >
    </div>";
$out .= "<div style='width:200px;'>".$loc['name']."</div>";
$out .= "<div style='width:400PX;'>".$loc['addy1']." ".$loc['city'].", ".$loc['state']." ".$loc['zip']."</div>";
// I tried ending the label here and then starting it up again after the select. That did not work.
//$out .= "</label>";

// Here is my added select, the onclick javascript function wraps this element.
// I want to prevent clicking on the dropdown from calling the javascript function.
$out .= "<div name='surveyorDiv' id='".$survDivId."' style='visibility:hidden; width:150px;'>";
$out .= "<select name='surveyor[]' id='surveyorId'><option value='null' selected='selected'></option>";
foreach($surveyor as $user) {
    $out .= "<option value='".$user['name']."'>".$user['name']."</option>";
}
$out .= "</select>";
$out .= "</div>";
// End of Select

//$out .= "<label for='".$i."'>";
$out .= "<div style='width:40px;>".$loc['signs']."</div>";
$out .= "</div></label>";
```

Here is my Javascript long-hand:

```javascript
<script language="javascript">
// Here is my javascript which changes the background color 
// of the primary Div and makes the select visible
function selectDiv(id) {
    var chk = document.getElementById(id);
    divId = parseInt(id) + 1000;
    surDivId = parseInt(id) + 9000;
    var div = document.getElementById(divId.toString());
    var surDiv = document.getElementById(surDivId.toString());
    if (chk.checked) {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#e4e4e4';
        surDiv.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '';
        surDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
</script>
```

In thinking through I tried removing the `label` wrap, which didn't change anything. I'd rather avoid breaking the primary `DIV`, so if there is anything I am missing please let me know.

Comment: Hmm... Tried anything like `onClick=" event.preventDefault() ;" `? If I get you right, though..

Comment: @Jari Worked perfectly in all browsers. Thanks! Please post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the solution for preventing default behaviour would be:

`onClick=" event.preventDefault() ;"`

Event here is passed as argument into function.

In IE 8 and some others there may be some issues, so the most compatible option would be:

```
if (event.preventDefault)
  event.preventDefault();
else
  event.returnValue = false ;
```

Comment: Regarding your edit referring to IE's potential issues, after your suggestion I did research `event.preventDefault()` and I did read about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1000597/1134705). Thanks for the addition, I have accommodated for this now.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is stop the event from bubbling up the dom. You can do that using `event.stopPropagation()` in the right event hander (click on an option?).

To get a more detailed answer, you would have to post the html and all javascript. The php is not relevant here as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try `event.stopPropagation()` and it behaved the same. Thanks again though