# jQuery asp.net, stopping postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-events

I have a text box and I want the user to be able to type in the TextBox and when they hit enter, I want jQuery to make a ajax call to a web method.
The problem is, when user hits the enter, the method is called but then the page refreshes due to the return.  I've tried using `return false` but with no results.

**Here is the code:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
   function serviceCall(getText) {          
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'ActiveDirectoryAutoFillWebService.asmx/TestMethod',
       data: "{'getId':'+ getText +'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (msg) {
       $("#divResult").html(msg.d);
       },
       error: function (e) {
       $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable " + e.name + " " + e.message);
     }
   });  
  //  return false;       This does not work      
}
function searchKeyPress(e) {
   if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) { e = window.event; }
       if (e.keyCode == 13) {              
           serviceCall(e)   
           //  return false;       This does not work         
       }          
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">      
    <div id="divResult" style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbSearchName" runat="server" onKeyPress="searchKeyPress(event); "></asp:TextBox>      

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone knows how I can accomplish this, please let me know.

Comment: so you do not want the page refresh ? is that what you want ?

Comment: Are you sure the searchKeyPress is getting as far as serviceCall? Have you tried e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: opensourcelover:  yes, i do not want the whole page to refresh/postback when the user hits the enter key in the textbox.  instead, if the user hits enter in the textbox, it should call the serviceCall method (which calls the webmethod)

Comment: Chris Dixon:  yes, I am sure the serviceCall method gets called (I have placed break points in the JS and code behind.  Also, I can see the printed out message prior to the page posting back).  I am not aware of e.preventDefault().  Can you explain what this is and how it may help?

Comment: Chris, e.preventDefault doesnt seem to work in IE but it did lead me to e.returnValue = false;.  If you post this as a response, i can mark it as correct

Comment: you're passing event object to jquery post function i.e. serviceCall(e)   . comment your Ajax post code and put alert and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the following functions on the event object:

- [stopImmediatePropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)
- [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
- [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

In your case, you can use

```
e.preventDefault()
```

This will stop the default action from happening.

Comment: Thanks.  While e.preventDefault doesnt seem to work in IE, this does:   e.returnValue = false;  Thanks for the response and I will mark this with an upvote but Chris Dixon responded first, so i think i should mark his as correct, if he posts his comment as a response.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think marking Chris's response as correct is... correct :) Sorry, I only scanned over the comments. Funny it won't work in IE, I'm pretty sure I've use the preventDefault with IE before. Oh well, glad you got it working.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it does not work in IE or if its a version of IE that is the problem.  Found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie  Thanks again for your response!

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. Your preventDefault (a member of the browser event object) isn't supported in IE. The preventDefault() function of jQuery's event object would solve that for you (but you'd have to wire your textbox to the keypress event differently).