# Backbone Marionette AppRouter passing invalid arguments to function calls on Internet Explorer 8 (IE8)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8, coffeescript, marionette

I've set up a Backbone Marionette application as follows in my application

```
CL.Modules.Users = (Users, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  Users.Router = class Router extends CL.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      'profile' : 'showProfile'
```

And I have a function showProfile() that takes an argument.

```
showProfile: (arg1) ->
  alert(arg1)
  arg1.preventDefault() if arg1?
```

In browsers other than IE8, arg1 is alerted as undefined, but on IE8, it is an empty string (I checked by using typeof). The problem is that `arg1?` checks to see if event is undefined and so `preventDefault()` is being called on an empty string on IE8, which is breaking the execution. I'm not sure how this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: This works fine for me. IE8 Win7. You will have to step through the backbone source to find the problem. It is very simple to follow.

Comment: Are you sure that showProfile is not called from somewhere else, did you check the stack trace when it is an empty String?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie