# IE error .JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'preventDefault'

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following code inside my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
<script>
function validateForm(e) {
    if ($("[name=ip]").val() == "" && $("[name=mac]").val() == "") jAlert('Please enter atleast one search value.', 'Message');
    e.preventDefault();
}
 </script>
```

but when accessing this Script on IE i will get the following error:-

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property
>   or method 'preventDefault'

while when accessing the web page that uses this script using Firefox, chrome it will work fine, can anyone advice please ?

Comment: how are you calling the function?

Comment: see [this other stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: Internet Explorer's event object doesn't have a `preventDefault()` function, you'll need to set its `returnValue` property to `false` instead. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventpreventdefault.htm

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Or use jQuery to bind the event.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Or that! I didn't notice the jQuery tag on the question.

Comment: How are you binding this event?  You should use jQuery to do that, that will fix this problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
//for IE
e.returnValue = false;

//for browsers supporting preventDefault()
if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
```

or short record:

```
(e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: Right, but as the OP is using jQuery, this sort of thing shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't always like preventDefault

Check to make sure the broswer like preventDefault, if it doesnt, use returnValue.

```
if(e.preventDefault) {
   e.preventDefault();
} else {
   e.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: but this will not work on any browser,, and the form will be submitted