# Abort/Cancel data transfer after ondrop if invalid file type

Tags: javascript, html, upload

Is there a way to abort/cancel file transfer after onDrop event in Javascript, if invalid file type is selected/dropped onto the drop area?

For instance, if only **.jpg, .png** file formats are allowed, but the user drags and drops onto the drop area a file that has a ***.gif** extension I would like to cancel automatically sending/uploading data to the server and notify that an invalid file format is selected?

simple example

```
div = document.getElementById('div');
div.ondragover = function(event){

   div.ondrop = function(event){

if(event.dataTransfer.files[0].type == 'gif'){
    abort/cencel upload here
    }
    } 


  return false;//cancelling ondragover to allow ondrop event 

    }
```

Comment: Some code please. Show how you detect a drop.

Comment: @Mohammed Joraid, updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are using html + js native `event` to capture the drop.

Here's how to get the info:

```
event.dataTransfer.files[0].name // to get the file name
event.dataTransfer.files[0].size // to get the file size
event.dataTransfer.files[0].type // to get the file type
```

Filter type:

First, you need to cancel the default behavior to prevent uploading.

```
event.preventDefault();
```

for IE use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ietDefault%29%20event.preventDefault%28%29;)

```
    if (event.preventDefault) 
    { 
      event.preventDefault(); 
    } 
    else 
     { 
       event.returnValue = false;
     }
```

Then you can analyze your data.

```
if(event.dataTransfer.files[0].type == 'gif')
{
    //show message
}
```

And then you can proceed with uploading using e.g. ajax

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "receivefile.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("X_FILENAME", file.name);
xhr.send(file);
```

[Full Article Source.](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-file-drag-drop-read-analyze-upload-progress-bars/)

Comment: Yes, I'm using plain Javascript.

event.preventDefault() for all browsers, or just for IE only?

Comment: I'm using event.preventDefault() for IE only and return false for other browsers. I was just going to write that and saw your updated answer.
Tried it and it worked.
Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I tried the implementation you offered before asking this question, but I put event.preventDefault/return false in the wrong place. That's why it didn't work at first. After reading your answer, changed the place and it worked (: