# JQuery Post Not Working With IE8 + 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using jquery to post a form. Works fine on all browsers apart from IE, IE does not seem to be picking up the "prevent default" as the browser is directing to "beta.php". Here is my code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#betaform").submit(function(e){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "beta.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data){
                    content = "<H2>Thank you, data received</H2>";
                    $("#betaform").empty().append(content);
                }

            });
        });

     });
```

Comment: Use `e.preventDefault();` as you've passed `e` through the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Also this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `event.preventDefault();`, use `e.preventDefault()`.

You've passed `e` through in the function:

```
$("#betaform").submit(function(e){
                               ^ here
```

So either change `e` to `event` or `event` to `e`.

Zach has also stated that `return false;` could be included too.

Make sure if you do include `return false`, it goes at the bottom of the function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#betaform").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "beta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                content = "<H2>Thank you, data received</H2>";
                $("#betaform").empty().append(content);
            }

        });
      return false; // here
    });

 });
```

Comment: Also may want to return false too

Comment: return false is/was not needed.

Answer (score 0):

We use this function for cross-browser support because event.preventDefault() doesn't exist in earlier version of IE.

```
function PreventDefault(event) {
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Comment: That is NOT needed with jQuery...and this is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The JavaScript submit event does not bubble in Internet Explorer.
>   However, scripts that rely on event delegation with the submit event
>   will work consistently across browsers as of jQuery 1.4, which has
>   normalized the event's behavior.
>
> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that
>   conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.
>   Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of
>   rules and to check your markup for these problems

from [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Go and check all tags inside form and check for attributes having value (submit, length, or method) and rename attributes on something like:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

into

```
<input type="submit" id="submision" name="valid" />
```