# Prevent text area ENTER behavior with autoresize height to content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a working text area that autoresize height according to input using JS function, I tried to add JS function to disable ENTER behavior adding new line but didn`t work.

```
<textarea id="title" name="title" class="autosize" placeholder="new post title" cols="42" rows="1">Post title</textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ihabovich/kepjdgnL/

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. However, I do recommend you move the keypress event handler inside the document ready function; just after your keyup handler.

Comment: @ventaur Moving the keypress event handler inside the document ready function got it fixed. Thanks for clearing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using internet explorer perhaps. It seems to work fine in the three browsers I was able to test in (Safari, Chrome and FF)

If you *are* using IE then have a look at this solution. 
[event.preventDefault() function not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: The only still issue is the paste input still have line breaks allowable.

Comment: In that case, you will want to filter out line breaks after a paste event. Javascript will allow you to remove the \n characters. This is a bit tricky though because these can be different between windows and other OS. http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Comment: JS was not precise handling the method. More accurate done through CSS: white-space: pre-line;