# How to redirect to a controller action from javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, datatable, gsp

I have a gsp page index where I have a data table. On Click of the edit icon I want to redirect to edit view. I have tried some code over here but no result. It is redirecting to the index page itself. Can anyone please help me on this please? Here are my attempts below ::

```
    $('#example').on('click', 'a.edit-reference_1st', function (e) {
                var selectRow = $(this).parents('tr');
                var control = this;
                var referenceId = $(control).attr('referenceId');
//              alert(referenceId)
                window.location.href = '<g:createLink action="edit" id="${referenceId}" />'             
//              window.location.href="${createLink(controller: 'audio', action:'edit')}"+'/'+referenceId;
            });
```

Comment: Try `window.location = "${g.createLink(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'edit')}/" + referenceId;`

Comment: @user1690588 thanks for your reply. Actually all the effort is working when I use this code `e.preventDefault();` without it nothing is working. thanks for your help.

Comment: That's great. Make sure you test this in IE because you may got error in browser console and preventDefault may not works (Ref# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000597/event-preventdefault-function-not-working-in-ie.

Comment: In IE there's a lot of problem. I would like to leave IE

Answer (score 2):

this happens in "client-land" (in your javascript in the browser).  you have to generate the link on server beforehand (e.g. put it in a js var) and then build the link on the client side. pseudo code:

```
var baseLink = '<g:createLink action="edit" id="ID"/>';
$(..., function(e) {
    ...
    window.location.href = baseLink.replace("ID", referenceId);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply,Now it is calling the controller method but after that loading the index page instead of edit