# Django JQuery AJAX submit form POST request refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have a login form for which I want the client to send AJAX POST request as below with error handling. In case of validation/authentication errors, I don't the page to be reloaded or refreshed to the url corresponding to POST request Handler`(/users/login/)` with the JSON string received from `login` view's response. I tried using `event.preventDefault()` as suggested by many answer on SO but could not make it work. Any clue as to what is going wrong here? I don't think this to be a Django issue. I know that the `onsubmit` is triggerred because the window redirects to the POST handler URL `/users/login/` with the expected JSON string response - `{"error": ["Entered mobile number is not registered"]}`

**JQuery code**

```
$("#loginform").on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("Was preventDefault() called: " + event.isDefaultPrevented());
            console.log("form submitted!");
            var url = "/users/login/";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url:url,
                data: $("#loginform").serialize(),
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                    if(result.indexOf('errors')!=-1 ){
                        console.log(data);
                        if(data.errors[0] == "Mobile number and password don't match")
                        {
                            $('.login-error').text("Mobile number and password don't match");
                        }

                        else if(data.errors[0] == "Entered mobile number is not registered")
                        {
                            $('.login-error').text("Entered mobile number is not registered");
                        }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        window.open("/users/profile/");
                    }

                    //var result = JSON.stringify(data);
                    // console.log(result);

                }
            })

    });
```

**View Handler**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mobile_number = request.POST.get('mobile_number', '')
        password = request.POST.get('password', '')

        data = {}

        user_queryset = User.objects.filter(mobile_number=mobile_number)

        if len(user_queryset) == 0:
            data['error'] = []
            data['error'].append("Entered mobile number is not registered")
            # return JsonResponse(data)

        elif len(user_queryset) == 1:
            email = user_queryset[0].email

            user = auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                auth.login(request, user)

            else:
                data['error'] = []
                data['error'].append("Mobile number and password don't match")

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-primary" id="login">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
            <h1>&nbsp;</h1><h3>&nbsp;</h3>
                <h2 class="section-heading">Login to your profile</h2>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
            </div>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
            <h2>&nbsp;</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
            <form id='loginform' action='/users/login/' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset >
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="mobile_number" id="mobile_number" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Number" value="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
                        </div>
                </fieldset>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl btn-block">LOG IN</button><br><br>
                <span class="login-error"></span>
                <h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1>&nbsp;</h1>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you try to debug JS/Python and see if the ajax is actually triggered/it goes into your submit handler? Also try to add return false; at the end of the submit handler in JS.

Comment: You can also have a look at this page, which show ajax submit and form validation: http://jsn-techtips.blogspot.nl/2014/04/django-show-form-validation-error-with.html

Comment: @BogdiG : Yes, I know it is triggerred because the window redirects to the POST handler URL `/users/login/` with the expected JSON string response - `{"error": ["Entered mobile number is not registered"]}`. I should mention this in the question.

Comment: @anon Try return false; at the end of the .submit handler and remove event.preventDefault().    return false; will actually call automatically preventDefault() and stopPropagation() under the hood. or just add event.stopPropagation() as well in adition to event.preventDefault()

Comment: @BogdiG : I tried `return false` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `event.preventDefault();`, it might be a good idea to also call `event.stopPropagation()` in this case.

Comment: If the handler function has an error, the browser will stop the execution and proceed with the normal event handling, as you're describing. 
if you're using IE, the event object might not have the `preventDefault()` method. In this case you can refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000606/74632

Answer (score 0):

Use : 'event.preventDefault()' or 'return false' after the ajax call.

Comment: I have already used event.preventDefault() as you can see in the second line of the JQuery code section