# Javascript inline display difference across browsers?

Tags: javascript, inline-code

I have the following inline Javascript code:

```
<a href="javascript:{ document['example'].src = 'cube.png'; document.getElementById('constructor').innerHTML = 'Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();'; }">Cube</a>
```

For your poor tired programmer eyes, here's the expanded version:

```
document['example'].src = 'cube.png';
document.getElementById('constructor').innerHTML = 'Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();';
```

This code acts as a hyperlink that changes the `example` image to an image of a 3D cube and changes a `<pre id="constructor">`'s content to the appropriate constructor. (This is obviously a tutorial page).

This works perfectly fine in Chrome, but in other  browsers, I get either a new page or the whole page's content changed to:

```
Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();
```

What is the problem with the code? What puzzles me is that it's valid in a browser and not in another. It's as if the script couldn't find the 'constructor' element and proposed the whole page as a fallback. I'm far from being a Javascript expert, so that's just a wild guess.

Comment: NB: `document['example']` is not a good way to reference an image. I assume it's the `name` of an image, then you should be using `document.images['example']`, or use an `id` and `getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just answer "What is the problem with the code?"

The `href` behaves differently than any onXXX event (hence javascript: protocol). It kind of tries to load new document and put something inside. The worst thing, it catches all output. So, to make it work as-is, you need to catch all statement values as assignments:

```
var x = document['example'].src = 'cube.png';
var y = document.getElementById('constructor').innerHTML = 'Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();';
```

all in `javascript:{...}` of course.

Also some good comments and explanations here: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/9899.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Well I must say I've never seen this kind of notation in an anchor link, using the braket to put some code in it I mean.

I tried in Chrome, it did work indeed, but not in FireFox.

You may want to try like that though:

```
href="javascript:(function(){ document['example'].src = 'cube.png'; document.getElementById('constructor').innerHTML = 'Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();'; })()"
```

But to be honest I would just create an helper function and call it directly like:

```
href="javascript:myFunction('Cube')"
```

Or something like that (even better would be to dynamically attach an event listener to the anchor link)

Comment: Oh well, perhaps it's just not legal code. I coded a function that indeed does it for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo(); return false;">Cube</a>
```

---

In your JavaScript code:

```
function foo () {
    document['example'].src = 'cube.png';
    document.getElementById('constructor').innerHTML = 'Mesh mesh = new Mesh.Cube();
}
```

Comment: You would also need to adjust your CSS so that it makes the a element look like a link:  style="color:blue;text-decoration:underlined;cursor:pointer;cursor:hand;"

Comment: @jmort That's unrelated. However, text-decoration:underline, not underlined. Also, you are setting the cursor property twice which doesn't make sense.

Comment: The onclick is really unrelated. I want it to be a link which causes a Javascript action. Why would I attach an event? Oh well, I got it fixed anyway.

Comment: @Lazlo You want to execute JavaScript code when the user clicks on the link. The proper way to do this is to use the `onclick` attribute, not the `href` attribute.

Comment: @Lazlo Check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245868/what-is-the-difference-between-the-different-methods-of-putting-javascript-in-an Here it is explained why onclick is the proper way to do it.