# 'undefined' is not a function evaluating el.click() in Safari

Tags: javascript

I would like to run a js function on pressing Enter button.
Everything works great in IE, Chrome and Opera, but I get an error (explained below) in Safari.

I need a **pure Javascript** solution, **not jQuery**.

This is the **function**:

```
function pressSearch(e) {
    if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) {
        e = window.event;
    }
    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : 
                   ((e.charCode) ? e.charCode : 
                   ((e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : 0));
    if (charCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('enterSearch').click();
    }
}
```

This is the **HTML**:

```
<input type="text" id="searchKey" onkeypress="pressSearch(event)">
<div id="enterSearch">Search</div> // This is the "button"
```

I get this **error**:

```
// Safari
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function 
    (evaluating 'getElementById('enterSearch').click()')
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I've fixed the Mozilla Firefox error.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into firefox, but got no error... Can you provide a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I upvoted just because of the "I don't want jQuery" line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you take a look at the [HTML DOM Level 2 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/ecma-script-binding.html), the `click()` function is only defined for `HTMLInputElement`, so while certainly not very user-friendly Safari doesn't need to implement that.

The correct way to trigger an event for modern browsers is in [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/):

```
// First create an event
var click_ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
// initialize the event
click_ev.initEvent("click", true /* bubble */, true /* cancelable */);
// trigger the event
document.getElementById("someElement").dispatchEvent(click_ev);
```

Here's jsfiddle that works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/y5yW9/6/

Comment: I have tried this creatEvent but its not working for IE8 as you mention. But what other option if I have to run this Event for IE8 or anyelse option. Because I am stuck with this situation. Thank you if you will give me answer

Answer (score 2):

You're triggering a click event on a `div`which would have no implicit click handler.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue while working on [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669617/instagram-auto-like-bookmarklet/10670209#10670209).  What I came up with is the following for triggering click events in safari(as well as other browsers, of course):

```
var t = document.getElementById('someidhere');
if (document.dispatchEvent) {
    var e = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,    // Window associated with the event
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    });
    t.dispatchEvent(e);
} else if (document.fireEvent) {
    t.fireEvent('onclick');
} else if (t.click) {
    t.click();
}
```

According to @Dennis, your code already works for Firefox, however this code should work in Firefox anyway as of version 79.0(the version it was tested in).

Note that [`initEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) has been deprecated.  The new method of creating the event through the Event constructor [doesn't work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event#Browser_compatibility) in Internet Explorer, however.

Comment: Did you mean if (t.click()) or if (t.click) ?

Comment: @PaulBrannan Fixed, as well as updated in other regards.

Answer (score 1):

A `div` element has no click event handler defined per default. So, first you need to apply a click event for the enterSearch div, e.g. `<div id="enterSearch" onclick="submitSearch()">Search</div>`. Otherwise the button itself won't be clickable.

To execute an event programmatically, use this construct:

```
function pressSearch(e) {
    if (typeof e == 'undefined' && window.event) {
        e = window.event;
    }

    var charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : ((e.charCode) ? e.charCode : ((e.keyCode) ? e.keyCode : 0));
    if (charCode == 13) {
        var a = document.getElementById('enterSearch');

        if (typeof a.onclick == "function") {
            a.onclick.apply(a); // binds the scope of onclick to a
        }
    }
}
```

I could not validate this for IE, but it works with Safari.

Comment: This won't work with event handlers added via 'addEventListener'.

Comment: But addEventListener won't even work for IE. Thus, I recommended the "old" fashioned way if possible. Or alternatively an IE-Others switch has to be inserted for programmatically binding of events.

Comment: Ok, when using programmatically event binding it seems that the solution from Daedalus is the most generic. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById('enterSearch')`

should be `document.getElementById('enterSearch')`

Comment: my real code has `document.blabla` in it and it does not work