# How to check if click() is defined for the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that Safari does not support click() of Jquery.

So I have the following two implementations for click event:

For Safari:

```
var foo = document.getElementById(some_id.id);
var ce= document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
ce.initEvent("click", true, true);
foo.dispatchEvent(ce);
```

For other browsers other than Safari:

```
document.getElementById(some_id.id).click();
```

Now, my problem is, if I put both pieces into my code, I have to apply some sort of conditional to check, if one fails, use the other. Yet I'm unable to find a way to check that.

When I use  document.getElementById(some_id.id).click();  Safari gives the following error:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'document.getElementById(del_id.id).click()')**

How could I catch&handle this error, or check if this error occurs in a conditional? So I could make the code to try the other piece?

I tried `typeof (document.getElementById(some_id.id).click()) == undefined` but no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: `x.click()` *calls* the function. If you wish to simply see of `x.click` is not defined: `x.click === undefined` - but doesn't jQuery handle the details with `$(elm).trigger("click")`?

Comment: my guess: if(jQuery.prototype.click){//click-function is defined}

Comment: jQuery supports the `$(Element).click()` for all Browsers.

Comment: two more points for rep and I too can down vote this , as its not even jQuery for the selector of the element.

Comment: No I do not think jQuery supports click() in safari, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744202/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-el-click-in-safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis. In your comparison use only: `.click === undefined`.