# calling click() function on html element in jasmine-phantomjs test

Tags: javascript, jasmine, phantomjs

I run my tests with Karma and PhantomJS:

> INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.32 server started at http://localhost:9876/
>   INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8
>   (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket kVOvdbbgtIeUQuV8AAAA wit

In the that test I want to click on the paragraph (p) to get my event-feedback:

```
// given 
var element = appendToBody("<p id='hello-p'>Hello Hello World!</p>");

element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log("1");
});

// when
var p = document.getElementById("hello-p");

console.log(p);
// LOG: <p id="hello-p">Hello Hello World!</p>
console.log(p.id);
// LOG: 'hello-p'

p.click(); // calling click
```

I end up having this message:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'p.click()')

Q: why p could be undefined?

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744202/undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-el-click-in-safari when googled. that was fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Ok.
Bacause PhantomJS based on webkit, I have to create/send event like this:

```
  var cle = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
  cle.initEvent("click", true, true);
  var elem = document.getElementById('hello-p');
  elem.dispatchEvent(cle);
```