# Invoke Angular2 click event on non InputElement

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am testing a component which has a click input on a div.

```
<div (click)="handleClick(someArgs)"></div>
```

Now I want to validate the behaviour in a test. I tried using `.click()` on the native element:

```
const elem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('my-selector'));
elem.nativeElement.click();
// Check for desired changes
```

However this only works in specific browsers since `.click()` seems to only be defined for HTMLInputElements ([Relevant StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764734/3388748)). I get the following error `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating elem.nativeElement.click()')` for a couple browsers.

What is the best way to invoke a click event on a non HTMLInputElement?

Comment: In which browsers do you get this error? Please specify

Comment: I had this issue using PhantomJS 1.9 (but not using 2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is calling `triggerEventHandler()` on `DebugElement`

**triggerEventHandler**

> Triggers the event by its name if there is a corresponding listener in
>   the element's listeners collection. The second parameter is the event
>   object expected by the handler.
>
> If the event lacks a listener or there's some other problem, consider
>   calling nativeElement.dispatchEvent(eventObject)

From testing documentation

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#trigger-event-handler

Comment: calling `elem.triggerEventHandler('click', null)` did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you want to trigger click on html elements using plain js you have to call the event which is defined on the element.

UPDATE: if you are using Jasmine, you can try calling `trigger` on the element:

```
const elem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('my-selector'));
elem.nativeElement.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Just tested it and seems not working, however the update works fine @yurzui

Comment: This did not work using Phantomjs 1.9.1 and TypeScript: `TypeError: 'undefined is not a function (evaluating elem.nativeElement.trigger('click')')'`.