# CSS to hide table and show a tr

Tags: javascript, css, visibility, css-tables

I wanted to hide a table on load and show one of its children td based on class name.
Is it possible to do it with CSS?

I tried to do it but I think its inheriting from table which is hidden by display:none;

Comment: the title says show hide a tr and yet you explicitly ask about showing a td ...

Answer (score 9):

If you hide the table, all of the content within the table will be hidden.

You want to hide all the `<tr>`s and only show per class

```
tr{
  display:none;
}
tr.showInit{
  display:table-row;
}
```

Comment: lost half an hour because i used `display:block` instead of `display:table-row` you have a grateful dev on the other side of the ocean (:

Comment: Ditto on @microspino.

Answer (score 5):

You can't show a child of a hidden parent.

However you can hide all the other `<td>`-s and show just the one you need.

```
<style>
td { display: none }
td.shown { display: table-cell }
</style>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td> hidden </td>
        <td> hidden </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="shown"> shown </td>
        <td> hidden </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> hidden </td>
        <td> hidden </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpchh/)

---

**UPDATE**

Using JavaScript

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");

for ( var i = 0, size = tds.length; i < size; i++ ) {
    if ( !hasClass( tds[i], "shown" ) ) {
        tds[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpchh/1/)

[`hasClass()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898748/1499781) function

Comment: Is it possible via JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show the **child** and hide a **parent**   .. That is not possible.

Instead hide all the **td's**  you don't want to show ..