# Check if Div with specific Class exists in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm trying to modify an existing webpage by inserting my own Javascript file in it. I'm setting a background Image for this webpage by inserting a new Div through my Javascript and setting background of that div to image url. For centering this image on background and to make it occupy the whole webpage, I'm using

```
'background-size': 'cover'
```

property. This of course doesn't work in older IE versions.

I want to fix it, I'm thinking of zooming in the image by specific ratio calculated using page height/width and image height/width.

So I want to detect if browser is IE. I checked the webpage and it has this code that detects browser and add's a div with class IE.

```
<!--[if lte IE 5]>
  <div class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <div class="ie ie6">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <div class="ie ie7">
<![endif]-->
```

**My questions is** how do I detect if this page has a div with class ie. Also, I would really appreciate if someone could suggest an alternative way of setting a background image on the webpage page that occupies it fully irrespective of dimensions of image/page and image center is focused.

Comment: why do you need JS to detect the IE class? Why not target the element in the stylesheet? with div .ie {different style here}. Also for background-size specifically you can use a filter as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you load the jQuery library in your page, which you can link from the Google CDN, this is a very simple matter.

CDN: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Usage:
    $("div.className").first()

Otherwise this will require some more effort ... the best possible way to deal with this is add an id attribute to the div element like so:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
```

And then use the document.getElementById function to retrieve your div tag.

```
document.getElementById('myElement');
```

To see if it has a specific class after this addition please refer to this other post:
[Test if an element contains a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to loop through all of the `<div>` elements on the page, until one matches the `className` you are looking for. Something like:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(i=0; i<div.length; i++) {
    if(div[i].className.match(/(^|\s)ie(\s|$)/)) {

        // Code to Do your IE Stuff Here

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var ie = document.getElementsByClassName("ie");
  if(ie.length > 0) {
    alert("It's IE!");
  }
}
```

This should answer your first question, although I agree that there are better solutions for your overall goal.

Comment: I don't think IE (at least not the older versions) support the `getElementsByClassName()` method?

Comment: No, only IE 9 and above do, so this is the worst possible way to look for divs that only exist in those browsers :) See http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html

Comment: You are right - I just found this site saying the same: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname