# How to tell if an HTML element has a particular class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, class, css

Is there an easy way to tell if an HTML element has a specific class? For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('something');
if (element.class == 'car')
```

Of course an element can have multiple classes, so maybe the `if` statement would have to be of the following form?

```
if (element.class.includes('car'))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Please use the search before asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementById("myid");
if (element.classList.contains("myclass")) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Read more on element#classList here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.classList

This link also contains a polyfill for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If using jQuery is an option you can use `hasClass()` see http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

If not you can take a look at pure JS implementation - [Test if an element contains a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

Comment: Does the downvoter care to drop a comment ?

Answer (score 0):

For strange reasons the name of the member containing the class(es) is `className`, not `class`. Multiple class names are separated by space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
 class = document.getElementById("{id_of_element").getAttribute("class");
```

then

```
 String[] vals = class.split(" ");
 var match = false;
 for (i = 0; i < vals.length;i++) {
   if (vals[i].equalsIgnoreCase('car') {
     match = true;
     break;
   }
 }

 if (match) {
  //do something
 }
```

HTH.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PXJ9a/

Comment: What if you're looking for `cat` and it has `catalog`? -1

Comment: @PeeHaa埽,@Doorknob fair enough. I didn't think it through :). Nonetheless, you can access the value of the class attribute by part one.