# Slide div every click once right and then on same click back again(left)

Tags: javascript, html, css

My div goes right but when i click again should be back to its original location.....

i tried many stuff but not working.Here is my code...
How do i reverse it when clicked. on every click it should be the reverse of the previous action i.e.
if on click the div moves right then on next click at the same location it should move left similar to a pendulum

```
<html>
<head><title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[

window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("d2").onclick = slideIt;
};

function slideIt()
{
var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("d1");
var stopPosition = 50;

if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) < stopPosition )
{
    slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 2 + "px";
    setTimeout(slideIt, 1);

}
/*
if(parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) > stopPosition )
{
    slidingDiv.style.left = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.left) + 2 + "px";
    setTimeout(slideIt, 1);

}*/
  }

//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d1" style="position:absolute; left:-131px;">
<div style=" float:left" >click here to slide the div</div>
<div id="d2" style=" float:left" >click here to slide the div</div> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest you to use http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: @MateiMihai I disagree. No point for such a simple application. All that's needed here is to check whether the div is in position and if so change the direction of movement.

Comment: i dont want use jquery....

Comment: @gvee- hw to change the direction... i didnt get u...

Comment: @user3292824 see my answer below. Note that to go right you add to the `left` attribute (+2) and to go left you take away from that value (-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JavaScript with this one

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){   $("#d2").click(function(){
            if($("#d1").css("left") <="-131px") 
                {
               $("#d1").animate({left:'250px'});        
                }   
             else   {
            $("#d1").animate({left:'-131px'});      
                        }   
       }); 
  });
</script>
```

This will work fine

Good Luck..

Comment: Don't forget to add the JQuery Library <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

Comment: the code doing that as well. If you click on "click here to slide the div" it will move the div to left..

Comment: If U want to move the div by clicking on any where on the text just change the  $(document).ready(function(){   $("#d2").click(function()       to                                                     $(document).ready(function(){   $("#d1").click(function().

Comment: i made a mistake above. im sorry.  after i get d divs to right(the very first action on click), i want to shift it back to its original location by click. now including this i want to also click-drag n release div d1 to its original location(back left where it was)

Comment: If I understand it rite you want to add the effect of "click-drag n release" Is it the case? You mean when you drag the div to right and when you release the div it move back to is original position?

Comment: See the very first click shifts d divs to right side. Nw only for the left-side shift i want both "click" and "click-drag and release" with mouse to the original location.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's how I have done things...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xDDX8/2/**

### HTML

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">click here to slide the div</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#d1 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
}
.moveLeft {
    color: blue;
}
.moveRight {
    color: lime;
}
```

### Javascript

```
window.onload = bindEvents();

function bindEvents() {
    document.getElementById('d2').onclick = slideIt;
}

// Global variables
var slidingDiv = document.getElementById('d1'); // Cache the element
var timeout = 0;
var minPosition = 0;
var maxPosition = 50;

function slideIt() {
    // Work out current position
    var currentPosition = slidingDiv.offsetLeft;

    // Check which direction to move
    if (hasClass(slidingDiv, 'moveRight'))
    {
        // Have we hit our movement limit?
        if (currentPosition <= minPosition)
        {
            // remove all classes and set a class to move the other direction
            slidingDiv.removeAttribute('class');
            slidingDiv.setAttribute('class', 'moveLeft');
            // Clear our timeout
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            // Still space to move so let's move a few pixels (-)
            slidingDiv.style.left = (currentPosition - 2) + "px";
            timeout = setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
        }
    }
    else // all comments as above really
    {
        if (currentPosition >= maxPosition)
        {
            slidingDiv.removeAttribute('class');
            slidingDiv.setAttribute('class', 'moveRight');
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        else
        {
            slidingDiv.style.left = (currentPosition + 2) + "px";
            timeout = setTimeout(slideIt, 1);
        }
    }
}

// Function to test whether an element has a specific class
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}
```