# Copy div class from the clicked item and insert into another div

Tags: javascript

I currently have a list of `<li>`'s. Each `<li>` will have a color class defined, example: `.color-blue`, `.color-red`, `.color-green` - like so:

```
<ul id="listings">
  <li class="layer block color-blue" id="item-1"></li>
  <li class="layer block color-red" id="item-2"></li>
  <li class="layer block color-green" id="item-3"></li>
</ul>
```

**How do I copy/get the color class of the specific `<li>` item that is clicked?**

I have my click listener in place and also know how to get the `<li "id">` however not sure on the specific class though.

```
/* Click listener */
document.getElementById("listings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //console.log(e.target.id + " was clicked");
});
```

Comment: Just read the className out, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("listings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    if (el.tagName == "LI") { // Use only li tags
        for (i=0; i < el.classList.length; i++) {
            if (~el.classList[i].indexOf('color')) {
                var color = el.classList[i];
                console.log('color class found: '+color);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bHJ3n/

Answer (score 0):

You can use (jQuery):

```
$('ul').find('li.layer block color-blue')
```

Or

```
$('ul#listings').find('li.layer block color-blue')
```

Comment: I dont see any jQuery tag here

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById("listings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   alert(e.srcElement.className);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yTtH3/)

**UPDATE**(since it is not working in Firefox as pointed from Sai):

To work also in Firefox try this:

```
document.getElementById("listings").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
   alert(target.className);
});
```

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/yTtH3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Or... you can not use jQuery as that wasn't in the original question and would be wasteful to include unnecessarily.

Here's a solution that works in vanilla JS:
[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWa8X/)

Essentially because you're lumping the colour among the other classes you have to split them into an array and iterate over them until you find the one that starts 'color-'. I would recommend you use a custom attribute instead, like `data-color="blue"` as that would mean you could just retrieve it with:

```
e.target.getAttribute('data-color');
```