# Javascript check if array item has class error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Javascript:

```
var ulKopjes = document.getElementsByClassName("tabKopjes")[0].getElementsByTagName("li");
 for (j=1; j < (ulKopjes.length - 1); j++){
  debugger;
   if (ulKopjes[j].hasClass('activeTab')){
    debugger;
   }
 }
```

Is there an obvious reason that I get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'?
I checked the values in the array, those ar 'li' items, that's correct.

Comment: ulKopjes[j] is a dom element, so you have to wrap in a $()

Comment: You also seem to have a &#60; char in your code

Comment: My code is a part of XSLT. XSLT doesn't accept < in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('.tabKopjes').eq(0).find('li').each(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('activeTab')) {
       //do stuff
   }
});
```

or if the `li` are direct children of `.tabKopjes` use `.children` instead of `.find`

If you are just after the li with the class active tab you can do

```
$('.tabKopjes').eq(0).find('li.activeTab')
```

Comment: @OP This is the way it should be written using jQuery, utilize it if it's already there.

Comment: You're welcome! `eq(0)` is the first item in the found list like your `[0]` on the array. http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

`hasClass` is not a pure-native-JS method and it does not exist. It's a jQuery function, so you have to use jQuery to get your elements, for example:

`var ulKopjes = $('.tabKopjes:first > li');`

If you do not use jQuery, you have to use another way to check for a given class: [Test if an element contains a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

Comment: Can I also use $(document.getElementsByClassName("tabKopjes")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")); ?

Comment: Actually yes, you can, but why? The jQuery syntax is so much shorter.

Comment: I changed it to `var ulKopjes = $('.tabKopjes > li');`, this didn't work. Do I have to change my if statement too?