# How to match only part of a string in Javascript or for a string to contain

Tags: javascript, string, include, match, contains

I am trying to match one className called invalid. My classes have a default class of 'form-control' and another which is concatenated to the class by the class called ' invalid' if a mandatory field has not been supplied with data which makes 'form-control invalid.

My code works but I would like it to be more efficient by matching only the 'invalid' class and not the whole 'form-control invalid'.

```
if (txtCust.className != 'form-control invalid') {
btnSave.onclick = ""; 
}
```

Comment: Try `txtCust.classList.contains('invalid')` to check if the target has class `invalid` or not. And here's some doc of [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if an element contains a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898656/test-if-an-element-contains-a-class)

Comment: Thank you fuyushimoya, you have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(txtCust.className.indexOf('invalid') < 0)
```

The `indexOf()` method will return the starting index of the substring's starting point within a `String`. So for example:

```
String hello = 'hello';
hello.indexOf('el'); //would return 1
```

So if `indexOf` returns a number greater or equal to 0 then that means the substring exists within the String. If it's less than 0 (usually -1), it means that the `String` doesn't contain the substring you are looking for.

Comment: This is another way that I could have used but I have gone with the contains() method